# Displaying two XML listings side by side.

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I have two XML outputs from a program that I would like to include in a LaTeX document. I would like them to appear side-by-side each in its own box. So that a reader can compare the two outputs while reading the document. Can't seem to find a way to do this, without making images for each output and adding both as images/graphics. Could there be a better option?

Comment: Your title and tag doesn't really fit the question text. Shouldn't it be titled like "Displaying two XML listings side by side"?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use some verbatim environment or macro to display source code. The `listings` package is good for this and provides syntax highlighting, but unfortunately not for XML.

You should place each code then into a `minipage` environment with a width slightly smaller than `.5\textwidth`. Something along:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
  \lstinputlisting[breaklines]{file1.xml}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
  \lstinputlisting[breaklines]{file1.xml}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

The exact code depends if you need it as a floating environment, need captions etc.

Comment: Oh Great, the side-by-side works. I need to add a Caption for each file as well as a box around the code.

Comment: @user739807: You could either use the `title` or `caption` option. The option `frame=single` should add the box. All options are comma separated inside the `[ ]` argument.

Comment: I was about to comment that one should add a \noindent before the first minipage, especially if the above starts on it's own line,but I noticed you've put everything in a centered environemnt. Does this negate the need for noindent ? i.e. does centre gobble he preceeding space ?

Comment: @Carel: AFAIK `center` does generate no indent as it is a trivlist [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).  It would be strange centering it with a parindent added first. That's also the reason to use `{center}` instead of `\centering`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer is there a mean to align the two listings vertically (top or bottom) ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva: The optional argument of `minipage`: `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` for top or `[b]` for bottom should do the trick.