# Latex: adding text inform of a graphic

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying two XML listings side by side.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19098/displaying-two-xml-listings-side-by-side)

I have two xml outputs from a program that I would like to include in a latex document. I would like them to appear side-by-side each in its own box. So that a reader can compare the two outputs while reading the document. Cant seem to find a way to do this, without making images for each outout and adding both as images/graphics. Could there be a better option?

Comment: Double post due to migration.