# When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

After reading this question [Should I use center or centering for figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/2099), I want to know the answer of the following.

When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?

For example, should we use this one?

```
{%
\centering
<other contents>
}
```

or this one?

```
\begin{center}
<other contents>
\end{center}
```

Comment: @Werner I just looked at the post and don't think it adequately answered the questions.  We can always define a new environment to avoid the use of \begin so is there every a need for it?

Comment: The typical approach in such situations is to request more clarification from [the original answer(s)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/5764), perhaps issue a bounty. In extreme situations when a new (similar) question is asked, answers could be merged with an existing question, but otherwise there is duplication on the site which is avoided through closing...

Comment: @Werner if anything, can you merge David Carlisle's answers since his answers really shine light on when to use one over the other?

Comment: The best I can do is flag it for moderator attention, since they have the capability to merge content on the site.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

First of all, `\centering` needs a `\par` (or an empty line) before the closing brace

```
{\centering
  contents\par
}
```

Usually it's used inside some environment that provides the necessary `\par`, such as `minipage` or `figure`. Try

```
abc{\centering def}ghi
```

to see the effect.

The main difference with `center` is that `\centering` doesn't leave vertical space before and after it: `\begin{center}` is defined in terms of `trivlist`.

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
\def\centering{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
```

---

Note that it's an error to use

```
\center
```

because this will last “forever” (up to the end of the current group, anyway). The command exists just as a side effect of the existence of the `center` environment.

Answer (score 104):

The difference between `center` and `\centering` is that the latter just sets the paragraph parameters but the former is a *list* (actually implemented via `\trivlist`) as such, it gets the standard vertical spacing used by all LaTeX display environments such as `verbatim` or `verse` or `quote`, as well as theorems.

So if you just want to center something that is already vertically positioned (as is often the case inside a `figure` environment) then `\centering` is what you need, but if you want to implement a displayed construct that happens to need centred content, then `center` is what you should use.

Comment: So it would be appropriate then for it to be used as a title of a new idea of a long document then.  I wasn't thinking about the display environment advantages over the just centering it aspect.

Comment: @dustin possibly, although better to say used in the definition of such a title as it is better to use logical markup like `\section` or `\idea` in the document even if that is just defined to do some font and spacing commands. section titles often have other requirements though such as not allowing page breaks before following text.

Comment: For a formal document, of course, use one of those constructs but I was speaking of something informal such as notes.

Comment: @dustin bad habits is bad habits:-) even if you are just typing up some lecture notes and only you plan to ever see the document your future self will thank you (or me:-) if you stick `\newcommand\idea[1]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}` and use `\idea` rather than use `\begin{center}` explicitly.