# TikZ graph positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, graphs

I am trying to use TikZ to include a simple graph in a short document, but I can't get to position the image properly. Sorry if it is a bit stupid, but this is the first time I am doing something like this.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[auto=left,circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}
\raggedright
  Jméno: Alexandar Živkovič\\
  UČO: 325003\\
  \bigskip
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item %1)
      \pagebreak
    \item %2)
  Graf:\bigskip
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[vertex] (n1) at (3,3)  {1};
  \node[vertex] (n2) at (6,3)  {2};
  \node[vertex] (n3) at (7, 1) {3};
  \node[vertex] (n4) at (6, -1) {4};
  \node[vertex] (n5) at (3, -1) {5};
  \node[vertex] (n6) at (2, 1) {6};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n1/n3,n1/n5,n2/n1,n2/n3,n2/n4,n2/n5,n2/n6,n3/n1,n3/n2,n3/n5,n3/n6,n4/n2,n4/n5,n4/n6,n5/n1,n5/n2,n5/n3,n5/n4,n5/n6,n6/n2,n6/n3,n6/n4,n6/n5}
  \draw (\from) -- (\to);

  \end{tikzpicture}

  Počet sledů z vrcholu $1$ do vrcholu $6$ délky $5$:\smallskip

  \item %3)

  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: How exactly do you want to position it?

Comment: Between "Graf:\bigskip" and "Počet sledů z vrcholu $1$ do vrcholu $6$ délky $5$:\smallskip", preferably to the middle of the page. There would be some matrixes after that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a `\par` after `Graf:`. `bigksip` only takes effect at the next paragraph.  With

```
Graf:\par\bigskip
```

we obtain the desired result:

[image]

As @Frédéric suggested `\begin{center}...\end{center}` around the `tikzpicture` will work. However, this will have additional vertical space as per [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures) and [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering). Alternatively, you could use

```
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please also tell me how to align it to the center of the page?

Answer (score 3):

A simple and effective solution is to wrap the picture within `\begin{center}`and `\end{center}` . This will place it in the center, on the next line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[auto=left,circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}
\raggedright
  Jméno: Alexandar Živkovič\\
  UČO: 325003\\
  \bigskip
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item %1)
      \pagebreak
    \item %2)
  Graf:
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[vertex] (n1) at (3,3)  {1};
  \node[vertex] (n2) at (6,3)  {2};
  \node[vertex] (n3) at (7, 1) {3};
  \node[vertex] (n4) at (6, -1) {4};
  \node[vertex] (n5) at (3, -1) {5};
  \node[vertex] (n6) at (2, 1) {6};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n1/n3,n1/n5,n2/n1,n2/n3,n2/n4,n2/n5,n2/n6,n3/n1,n3/n2,n3/n5,n3/n6,n4/n2,n4/n5,n4/n6,n5/n1,n5/n2,n5/n3,n5/n4,n5/n6,n6/n2,n6/n3,n6/n4,n6/n5}
  \draw (\from) -- (\to);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  Počet sledů z vrcholu $1$ do vrcholu $6$ délky $5$:\smallskip

  \item %3)

  \end{enumerate}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič Thank by upvoting. ;-)