# Draw a tree-graph in Latex with Tikz or qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

[image]

Is it possible to draw tree-graphs like the image below in LaTeX?
I just need an idea of ​​how to write the first two levels of the tree.
I believe that from there I can continue...

thanks!!!!!

Comment: I don't have all of them but I used Tikz following the idea of ​​positioning points on the plane like on this page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33369/tikz-graph-positioning

Is there a better way or idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you are facing two problems: the global one is "how can one draws the tree?".  The local one, is "what are the vertices of the tree?".  Are the vertices clear for you?  In my opinion, the tree is more or less easy to draw even if you just start with TikZ.  The tricky part is to conceive the vertices and how to use them in a (normal) tree.  I would say that your vertices should be `pics` elements (maybe with an embedded `node`)...