# How do I fix the vertical spacing in documents which go over one page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir

When LaTeX is unable to fit content onto a page, it sometimes inserts a large amount of whitespace between the two elements that fit on the first page, rather than just leaving space at the bottom of the page.

Minimal example:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \newcommand{\Rectangle}{%
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,16); \end{minipage}%
  }

  \begin{document}
  \begin{center} Hello \end{center}

  \Rectangle

  \Rectangle
  \end{document}
```

I would like the spacing to be such that the whitespace is just at the bottom of the first page rather than the large hole in the middle of the text and the rectangle. This can be fixed by either using the `article` class instead of `memoir` or getting rid of the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` but neither compromise is satisfactory for me.

What is the best way to get the whitespace to appear at the bottom of the page?

Comment: `\raggedbottom`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard setting of `memoir` is `\flushbottom`: every page is flush to the bottom, unless a `\newpage` command appears (which may be implicitly issued by other commands.

So, issuing `\raggedbottom` for the whole document (or parts thereof) or `\newpage` for the page under question, will fill the bottom with white space.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why it does \flushbottom when I have the \begin{center}...\end{center} but not when I just have normal text?

Comment: @bryn: The `center` environment actually adds vertical space above/below it, cause it to be "bigger than expected." See [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: I agree with Werner, see if `\centering` can serve your purpose: `{\centering Hello \\ }`