# Image (figure) positioning

Tags: floats, positioning

I got two cases with images I wish to use within a document.

One is a logo, I would like to use it in the front page, at the top-right corner.

How do I do that?

The second are a drawings which I would like it to be (horizontally) centralized, and in between the paragraphs I have placed it. Point is at the final result, figures are positioned sometimes a paragraph or two later.

How can I enforce them to be exactly where I want them?

Comment: For the second, see for example [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: Considering the logo, it is not really a "figure", just part of the title. You can place it in the environment `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` to make it centered. As for the real figures, follow the Torbjørn's link.

Comment: **top-right** not center.

Comment: @tohecz: You shouldn't use `center` for images. It is intended for text only. See [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/2975) and [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/2975).

Comment: @MartinScharrer As far as OP does not use `\begin{figure}[h]\begin{center}...`, but only `\begin{center}`, it gives better spacing than `\centering`. The thing is, images shouldn't be places just "between paragraphs" so he should of course say `\begin{figure}[...]\centering...`

Comment: @tohecz: `center` will add vertical spacing, which is normally not wanted for images, especially not inside `figure`. Of course, if you want such a vertical spacing than it might be ok. I would add the skip manually. My `adjustbox` package can help with both: `margin=0pt <vertical skip above and below>,center`

Comment: @MartinScharrer IMHO, this discussion has no purpose. I would use `center` for a logo without hesitation and get what I would need. I could of course use `\centering`. Just a note: now I re-read the question and it seems that OP wants it flushed right anyways...

Comment: @Vivi: Thanks for nice feedback! You are very welcome! Have a look at [Why can't I login to chat.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79641) for the chat login issues, i.e. try http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login and http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

The position of float environments are discussed very often here at tex stackexchange. Some related questions are:

- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Whatever I think the biggest problem is the understanding of `\includegraphics`. The command doesn't require a floating environment. It's a simple "token" inside TeX. So to place a picture in the top right corner you can use standard methods like `\raggedright`, `\hfill` etc. Maybe you can also use [`scrpage2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrpage2) or [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). If you want to set a figure at a special place you can also use packages like [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) or [`atbegshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi).

---

The great package [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) can handle the positioning very easy. You can simple use:

Load the package with the option `export`:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

Then you can use `\includegraphics` as follows:

```
\includegraphics[<other options>,right=<optional width, normally \linewidth>]{<file name>}
```

Comment: You can right align an image by loading `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and then using `\includegraphics[<other options>,right=<optional width, normally \linewidth>]{<image file>}`.