# How do I align an image to center?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

How do I align an image to center?

In a beamer presentation I have a 2-3 items on a slide followed by an image.
The image is not wide enough to cover whole slide, so it leaves around 30% space from right. How do I adjust it to leave enough space on both sides?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outlook}
\begin{itemize}
\item apps
\item apps
\item apps
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{P2P}    
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It is enough to use the `center` enviroment:

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics{yourimage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: In general you should use `center` only with text. It adds vertical space before and after the content, which is not really what you want most the time for images, especially not for floats. See [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651) and [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650).

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Another issue: if your margins are asymmetrical, the image will be centered with a text block which may or may not be there, not the page itself.

Answer (score 33):

The third way is to use the `figure` environment, which is the best way in my opinion, since it provides the right mark-up. (`beamer` centers the figures by default.)

```
\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics{<your image>}
\end{figure}
```

In this case on may also add a caption with `\caption{<text>}`

Answer (score 28):

You could also do something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \caption{My caption}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{theImage}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Just a note here: `\centering` should come before `\includegraphics`

Comment: @Freefri This worked for me. \begin-\end{center} did not work.

Answer (score 23):

Here are two ways of achieving this:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{<your image>}
\end{center}
```

or

```
\hfill\includegraphics{<your image>}\hspace*{\fill}
```

The former may add some vertical whitespace, while the latter centers its contents on the line used.

Comment: Third way \centerline{\includegraphics...}, perhaps you want to add it. Fourth way {\centering \includegraphics...\par}

Comment: I personally think `\centerline` is just perfect to center single boxes like images. @YiannisLazarides

Comment: I tend to prefer the opening-closing environments. So, I do not like much to use `{\centering ...}` but prefer `\bgroup \centering ... \egroup`.

Comment: @cacamailg: For what it's worth, they are *equivalent*, as you'll find `\let\bgroup={ \let\egroup=}` in the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 19):

One simple way to center an image is to use the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option. It provides the `center=<width>` key to `\includegraphics`, which centers the image around the given width. It defaults to the `\linewidth`, so use:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
% ....

\includegraphics[scale=0.3,center]{P2P}
```

Inside a `itemize` this will center the image relative to the `itemize` text width, not to the frame.

Comment: how about to the left and top?

Comment: Strangely, I get different results when I put write `[center,scale=0.3]` instead of `[scale=0.3,center]`.

Answer (score 1):

`\centering\includegraphics{...}` — when the figure is smaller than the text width
`\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}` — when the figure is wider than the text width

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Using just `\centering\includegraphics{...}` would make the rest of the document from this point on centered if you don't take care of the grouping. Maybe you should add something explaining this too. And I think that nowadays there are better alternatives than `\centerline`...

Answer (score 1):

This helps me

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics[width= 365pt]{./figures/xyz.png}
\centering
\caption{The picture shows xyz architecture}
\label{fig:xyz}
\end{figure}
```

You can of course change the width and other things as per your case. The only major part is `\centering` which helps here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think `\centering` should go _before_ `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome note. 

I am not sure, if this has any impact. However, in my case it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
\end{center}
```

That's almost perfect for raw screenshots, as images will not overflow the visible content.

Comment: Same answer as those from Tobi (Apr 30 '12 at 20:58) and gcedo (Apr 30 '12 at 20:52).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tikz.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at (current page.center) node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

will place your image on the center of the page. This does not account for any header, however. 
If you have a header that is 1 cm tall you can move the picture to compensate thus:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node at ($(current page.center) +(0,-1cm)$) node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics{}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can also anchor the node to any corner of side of the page, thus achieving absolute positioning with complete control rather effectively.

(I realize this question is old, but the solution is versatile and offers excellent positioning control)

Comment: Example given doesn't work as written.  A node must have a label text.  When looking to adapt a solution to one's own problem, we shouldn't be stuck just trying to debug the solution.

Comment: No, a node does not need label text, it can be empty, so long as the curly brackets are there. 
I guess I should have added something other than \includegraphics{} in the node.

The example runs just fine, though you are right, I should have added both the package (tikz) and something to indicate the \includegraphics command needs to reference an image. Add tikz in the preamble and a path to the \includegraphics{} command and there is no issue.