# \centering doesn't seem to center my text

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center this page but it will not work.  All is get is for the first line to be indented about one "tab" space to the right, but the second line will not shift.  However, the first line's indent does not appear to be centered either.  Is it possible that the binding offset or the `indentfirst` package is interacting with this negatively?  All of the other pages seem to work just fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{36 pt}
{\centering
\textbf{\emph{\Huge{Since I Saw You Last,\\There's a Change Upon You}}}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{36 pt}
\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries\itshape
Since I Saw You Last,\\There's a Change Upon You
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\centering` and size change commands such as `\Huge` should *always* be used in a way that the end of paragraph is in scope of the command, otherwise you will get Huge text on a normal sized baseline, and inconsistent spacing. `\Huge` does not take an argument it is just `\Huge` not `\Huge{.....}`.

Comment: Note that underlining multiple lines of text with the "soul" package results in bad centering, too! I worked around this problem using soul's \ul{} on every line separately.

Answer (score 18):

You must end the paragraph before closing the group. I also suggest to use the switch variants of the font commands in this cases (less braces)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{36 pt}
{\centering\Huge\em\bfseries
  Since I Saw You Last,\\There's a Change Upon You\par
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compared to David's answer, this stays closer to the original in two respects: `\em` retains the semantic meaning of `\emph{}`, the actual formatting of which may be changed e.g. by the package `ulem` -- David's `\itshape` only _usually_ has the same effect in the output, sc. `\emph{}`/`\em` is set in italics by default. Keeping the `\centering` switch doesn't add any additional space after the heading -- as David's `center` environment does.

Comment: @doncherry True although those changes were intentional in my version. This is some kind of display quote definition so you want to set the font. The semantic of _emphasis in any font distinguished from the current one_ would almost certainly be wrong. Similarly while it's true that `center` adds vertical space the  thing to do is accept that and adjust the immediately preceding `\vspace` if necessary. (no criticism of this answer which answered the question as posed, just responding to your comment)

Comment: I had something like `\newcommand{\heading}[1]{{\centering\textbf{#1}}}`. "You must end the paragraph before closing the group." was the information I was missing. After adding `\\\` it works.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `center` environment, rather than the `\centering` declaration.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{36 pt}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\emph{\Huge Since I Saw You Last,\\ There's a Change Upon You}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```