# Centering long sentence causes strange vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

In the following MWE I have a centred piece of unbreakable text. Problem is that this causes an extra bit of vertical space, so that visually the centred text is not vertically centred between the two paragraphs. What is the best way to deal with this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\texttt{a~sentence~that~is~long~and~continues~with~the~reason~so~that~it~sticks~out~a~bit}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: @Martin I'm also interested to know why we get the extra vertical space just because of some horizontal text that's too long. (I just realised that I didn't add that in the original question)

Comment: Because Lists (of which `center` is one) add space before and after them.

Comment: @Martin: The question here is _not_ the extra space around the `center` environment (which of course also occurs without long unbreakable text). The question is why there's additional space only _before_ the environment! (So no, it's not a duplicate of that other question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use center (which is internally a list):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

{\par\bigskip\centering
\texttt{a~sentence~that~is~long~and~continues~with~the~reason~so~that~it~sticks~out~a~bit}
\par\bigskip}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You say: Don't use center (which is internally a list) do you mean in general? or just in such cases as above? Your solution looks less obvious than simply using a center environment, so it seems to me that something is strange with the center environment.

Comment: Well I would say in the majority of cases `center` is not the best choice (and similar `flushleft` and `flushright`). The idea to use a list structure to change the justification of a paragraph doesn't seems right. Generally I find it more natural to use commands like `\raggedright` or `\centering`.

Comment: If I simply did `\renewenvironment{center}{\par\bigskip\centering}{\par\bigskip}` are there any catastrophic consequences? I mean, I have always used `center` as if it acted like this and am somewhat surprised that something I thought was obvious is in fact not the case.

Answer (score 4):

You're wondering why there's more vertical space before than after the unbreakable text, right?

[image: output]

Ulrike told you a good way to deal with it, I'd like to explain a bit *why* this happens. The problem is indeed the somewhat unfortunate definition of the `center` environment. This starts with `\trivlist\centering\item\relax`, so it uses the `\centering` command inside a trivial list. Now `\item` places an (empty) label as the first object to be centered, and your unbreakable text doesn't fit on the line, so TeX decides to put it on the *next* line. You can visualize this by redefining `\trivlist` so that the label isn't empty anymore:

[image: visualization]

Note that the `LABEL` isn't centered since I defined it so that it sticks out to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\trivlist{%
  \parsep\parskip
  \@nmbrlistfalse
  \@trivlist
  \labelwidth\z@
  \leftmargin\z@
  \itemindent\z@
  %\let\@itemlabel\@empty
  \def\@itemlabel{\llap{LABEL}}
  \def\makelabel##1{##1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent left \hfill right
\begin{center}
\texttt{a~sentence~that~is~not~so~long}
\end{center}
\noindent left \hfill right
\begin{center}
\texttt{a~sentence~that~is~long~and~continues~with~the~reason~so~that~it~sticks~out~a~bit}
\end{center}
\noindent left \hfill right
\end{document}
```

I think you're safe if you redefine the `center` environment to use Ulrike's suggestion. Note the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`!

```
\renewenvironment{center}{\begingroup\par\bigskip\centering}{\par\bigskip\endgroup}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was indeed wondering about this lop-sided vertical space. Given that you say _unfortunate definition of the center environment_ makes me wonder if there is ever any use for it.

Comment: @Geoff: I said _somewhat_ unfortunate `:-)` As long as you only have short enough lines, the environment is quite satisfactory, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes long unbreakables appear; which makes me wonder whether I should simply do `\renewenvironment{center}{\par\bigskip\centering}{\par\bigskip}` and then I don't need to worry about it. Unless there is something that can happen that I don't know about.

Comment: @Geoff: See my edit.