# Vertical spacing around custom center environment followed by \noindent

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, indentation

Inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98839/48787) (to define a center environment with no vertical spacing):

```
\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\parskip=0pt\par\nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}
```

I defined my center environment with custom vertical spacings:

```
\newenvironment{mycenter}
 {\par\addvspace{1.5ex}%
 \nopagebreak\centering}
 {\par\addvspace{1.5ex}%
 \ignorespacesafterend}
```

But now I do not know how to implement the `\noindent` part in the original answer. What am I supposed to do?

(I am aware that I can solve it using the [`noindentafter`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/noindentafter?lang=en) package, but I am trying to understand how things work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{nscenter}
 {\setlength{\topsep}{1.5ex}\trivlist\item\relax\centering}
 {\endtrivlist}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{nscenter}
This is \\
centered
\end{nscenter}
and this is not indented. \lipsum*[3]
\begin{nscenter}
This is \\
centered
\end{nscenter}

And this is indented, because of the empty line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I always learn new things from your answers. **Visually**, yes, that is what I want. To understand better: Does your answer suggest that compared to `mycenter` macro above, your answer the **the** proper way? And does it suggest that what I am asking cannot be incorporated into `mycenter` macro? Further, is it possible to modify your macro such that the following paragraph is not indented when there **is** an empty line? (Because, perhaps, I never want indented paragraphs after a center environment.)

Comment: @blackened It's surely possible to have the behavior you'd like, but I can see no reason for it.