# Writing table side by side in Latex

Tags: tables, formatting, positioning

How to write these two tables side by side. I go through with [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-can-i-have-two-tables-side-by-side) 
but \quad is not working. Please Help.

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{1.5cm} | m{.75cm}| m{.75cm} |  m{.75cm}| m{.75cm}| m{.75cm} |  m{.75cm}| m{1.5cm} |}

\hline
\textbf{prime $p$:}  & $p_1$ & $p_2$ & $p_3$ & $p_4$ & $p_5$ & ... & $p_n < B_m$ \\ 

\hline
\end{tabular}\
\quad
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ | P{1.25cm} | P{2cm}|}
\hline
$p^{'}_1$  & $r_{1}^{1}$, $r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  \\
.  & . \\
$p^{'}_1$  & $r_{1}^{1}$, $r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  \\
$p^{'}_1$  & $r_{1}^{1}$, $r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  ,$r_{1}^{1}$  \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post fragments of code only. Provide a compilable document, please. You could wrap an outer `\begin{tabular}{cc}...\end{tabular}` around the two `tabular` environments to place them side by side

Comment: You might want to remove the `\centering` before the second table.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely certain, but [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98893/10478) supports my intuition/belief that `\centering` starts a new paragraph, or at least a new line. That is why your tables don't appear next to each other. I also fail to see the purpose of `\centering` in your code fragment. Maybe you want it before the first table, so that the entire construct of your two tables is centered. In that case you can solve two problems at once, by moving `\centering` before your first table.