# How to define a function with undefined number of arguments to draw bytefield with variable number of bitbox?

Tags: xparse, bytefield

I have to draw lots of bytefield with different number of bitbox with different shapes.

For that I define 3 functions:

1. *mybytefield* that takes a variable number of arguments (using xparse with `\SplitList` and `\ProcessList`) and defines the bytefield environment
2. *bitboxlist* that takes args in a sequential way and sends them to *mybitbox*
3. *mybitbox* that takes the 2 arguments needed for \bitbox in a sequence and invokes `\bitbox{\value{{bitfieldsize}}{#1}` when the 2 arguments are ready.

It almost works ... I can invoke `\mybytefield` with different numbers of args and it draws several bytefield **BUT** the position of the bitbox are wrong or "corrupted" by the `\ProcessList`call.

Any idea ?

Here is a sample code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newtoggle{newarg}
\toggletrue{newarg}
\newcounter{bitfieldsize}

\newcommand\mybitbox[1] {
\iftoggle{newarg}{
\setcounter{bitfieldsize}{ #1 }
\togglefalse{newarg}
}{
\bitbox{\value{bitfieldsize}}{#1}
\toggletrue{newarg}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\bitboxlist {  >{\SplitList{;}}m} {
\ProcessList{#1}{\mybitbox}}

\newcounter{instsize}
\NewDocumentCommand\mybytefield{m >{\SplitList{;}}m} {
\setcounter{instsize}{#1 - 1 }
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=1em]{#1}
      \bitheader{0-\value{instsize}} \\
      \ProcessList{#2}{\bitboxlist}
    \end{bytefield}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}}

\newcommand\staticbitbox[4] {
  \bitbox{#1}{#2} \bitbox{#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}

\mybytefield{32}{{28;part1};{4;part2}}

%should do
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=1em]{32}
      \bitheader{0-31} \\
      \staticbitbox{28}{part1}{4}{part2}
    \end{bytefield}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spurious spaces in your code (see reference 1).

I have added the needed `%` at the end of lines where spaces had been included.

You may also change the `center` environment to `\centering` because the former introduces additional vertical spacing

#### Reference

1. [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/16595)
2. [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{newarg}
\toggletrue{newarg}
\newcounter{bitfieldsize}

\newcommand\mybitbox[1] {% <- here
    \iftoggle{newarg}{% <- here
        \setcounter{bitfieldsize}{ #1 }% <- here
        \togglefalse{newarg}% <- here
    }{% <- here
        \bitbox{\value{bitfieldsize}}{#1}% <- here
        \toggletrue{newarg}% <- here
    }}

\NewDocumentCommand\bitboxlist {  >{\SplitList{;}}m} {% <- here
    \ProcessList{#1}{\mybitbox}}

\newcounter{instsize}
\NewDocumentCommand\mybytefield{m >{\SplitList{;}}m} {% <- here
    \setcounter{instsize}{#1 - 1 }% <- here
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=1em]{#1}
                \bitheader{0-\value{instsize}} \\
                \ProcessList{#2}{\bitboxlist}% <- here
            \end{bytefield}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}}

\newcommand\staticbitbox[4] {% <- here
    \bitbox{#1}{#2} \bitbox{#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}
\mybytefield{32}{{28;part1};{4;part2}}

%should do
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{bytefield}[endianness=big,bitwidth=1em]{32}
    \bitheader{0-31} \\
    \staticbitbox{28}{part1}{4}{part2}
  \end{bytefield}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]