# When should \begin{center}\end{center} ever be used?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, learning

I know that `\begin{center}\end{center}` cause excess white space so it is always suggested that `\centering` should be used which I use all the time.  What would ever justify the use this tag?

Maybe if you want a title (non official) at the top of a page?

What I mean is that you have a document and on page 3 you are going to discuss the `3 body problem` whereas you were on topic about the `2 body problem` previously?  Or would another environment suit that better still?

Comment: Technically this asks the same question as in [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764) So, technically, it is a duplicate...

Comment: At the request of the OP I have merged David's answer across to the older question.