# Two chemfig lewis diagrams side by side with labels below

Tags: chemfig

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig} %for chemistry diagrams

\begin{document}
   \vspace{10mm}
   \setatomsep{2em}
   \begin{center}
      \chemfig{%
         CH(-[:180]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})(-[:90]CH_{3})
      }
   \end{center}
   1-chloro-3-methylbutane
   \begin{center}
      \chemfig{%
         CH_{3}-[:0]CH_{2}-[:0]CH(-[:90]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})
      }
   \end{center}
   1-chloro2-methylbutane
   \vspace{10mm}
\end{document}
%
```

**output**:

[image: two chemfigs with labels all on their own line]

**desired output**:

[image]

What is the best way for me to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chemfig` provides the command `\chemname{<molecule>}{<name>}` for writing a name below a molecule. It has an optional argument for the vertical offset and if the molecules have a different depth possibilities are provided to align the names anyway. This is described with examples in section 12 *Writing a name under a molecule* in [`chemfig`'s manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chemfig).

With it both molecules can simply be written one after the other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig} %for chemistry diagrams

\setatomsep{2em}

\begin{document}

% the `center' environment should probably be a `figure'
% environment or maybe a newly declared `scheme' environment
% (with the help of the `newfloat' package) but it does its
% work here:
\begin{center}
  \chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
      CH(-[:180]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})(-[:90]CH_{3})
    }
  }{1-chloro-3-methylbutane}
  % separate both molecules by 2em:
  \qquad
  \chemname{%
    \chemfig{%
      CH_{3}-[:0]CH_{2}-[:0]CH(-[:90]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})
    }
  }{1-chloro2-methylbutane}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: the names seem to have nothing to do with the molecules?

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a `tabular` environment.

- The `\\` command separates each row of the table. I write `\\[2mm]` to add extra 2mm of vertical space between the rows.
- Within a row, the `&` command separates each column.
- The `{cc}` declares a two-column table, and the `c` means that the contents of each column is centred.

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig} %for chemistry diagrams

\begin{document}
   \setatomsep{2em}
   \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \chemfig{%
         CH(-[:180]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})(-[:90]CH_{3})
      }
  &
      \chemfig{%
         CH_{3}-[:0]CH_{2}-[:0]CH(-[:90]CH_{3})(-[:0]CH_{3})
      }
  \\[2mm]
   1-chloro-3-methylbutane
  &
   1-chloro2-methylbutane
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way:

- `\vspace{...}` doesn't do anything at the top of a page. (But `\vspace*{...}` does.)
- You probably ought not to use the `center` environment in the way that you do -- see **[this answer by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116601/25356)** for why `\centering` might be more appropriate than `\begin{center}...\end{center}`.

Comment: I don't believe `\begin{centering}` works for `chemfig`...wait did you mean `\begin{centering}` or `\centering`

Comment: @puk There is no `{centering}` environment, only a `\centering` command for formatting the current paragraph. It works well with `chemfig`'s formulae and schemes as they're just TikZ pictures in the end.