# Insert margin images in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats

I am using a two sided layout in LaTeX and have several places where white space could be filled with images instead of being included in the text flow. I cannot get a working figure with caption though.

What I have tried from similar questions:

Throws "Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }"

```
\marginpar{\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{myimage.jpg}
 \captionof{figure}{Caption text}}
\lipsum[1-2]
```

This works but does not appear in the `\listoffigures`:

```
\marginpar{  
\centering{  
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{myimage.jpg}  
}  
Caption text  
}
```

The caption is supposed to have a generated index and link to the list of figures.

EDIT: a longer example

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}  

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{{images/}}



\geometry{  a4paper,
            twoside,
            includemp,
            includehead,
            top = 30mm,
            headsep = 10mm,
            bindingoffset = 10mm,
            inner = 20mm,
            outer = 40mm,
            bottom = 45mm,
            marginparsep = 10mm,
            marginparwidth = 30mm
}
\savegeometry{myText}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter about XY}
 aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo i

%%
% image with caption to go to the margin with its caption
%%
 \begin{figure}[t!bp]%
    \begin{center}%
        \includegraphics{ant}%
        \caption[Caption]{Caption text}
        \label{label}%
    \end{center}%
\end{figure}%

% creates the image in the margin but without link in TOC and list of figures
\marginpar{  
\centering{  
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{ant.jpg}  
}  
Caption text  
} 

 aeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo 

 \end{document}
```

EDIT:
This is working for me, why are the {} wrong?:

```
\marginpar{  
\centering{  
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}  
}  
\captionof{figure}{Caption text}
}
```

Also: adding a different text for the index tabel with

```
\captionof{figure}[table text]{Caption text}
```

causes "Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }."

Comment: What does not work for you in the first code snippet? Using it in a minimal document works without problem.

Comment: In a minimal document it throws a "undefined control sequence in line" \captionof{figure}{Caption text}}

Comment: You need either the [`capt-of`](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package loaded. The latter is preferred (`\usepackage{caption}`).

Comment: This works fine but the caption is not included in the figure table.

Comment: Please post a minimal example. It is not easy for us to help when we don't know your preamble etc. Having copy ready to copy'n'paste massively increases your changes to get proper help.

Comment: @RootRaven Please edit to include a full MWE, which is a full document showing the problem that we can compile.

Comment: No problems where with your example if I use the `demo` option for `graphicx` (to avoid needing your pictures). Do you get the problem with _exactly_ that file? If so, add `\listfiles` and edit the resulting file list from the `.log` into the question.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand you right. I have changed the part of your MWE for the image in the margins. It should compile now.  I added package `caption` in the preambel and corrected the call of `\centering` (without `{}`!). And I added `\listoffigures` to show that the image in the margin listed there. I use the `example-image-a.jpg` from package [MWE](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{varwidth}  

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}       % <============================
\usepackage{showframe}     % <============================
%\graphicspath{{images/}}

\geometry{  a4paper,
            twoside,
            includemp,
            includehead,
            top = 30mm,
            headsep = 10mm,
            bindingoffset = 10mm,
            inner = 20mm,
            outer = 40mm,
            bottom = 45mm,
            marginparsep = 10mm,
            marginparwidth = 30mm
}
\savegeometry{myText}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Chapter about XY}
 aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo i

%%
% image with caption to go to the margin with its caption
%%
 \begin{figure}[t!bp]%
    \begin{center}%
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
        \caption[Caption]{Caption text}
        \label{label}%
    \end{center}%
\end{figure}%

% creates the image in the margin but without link in TOC and list of figures
\marginpar{  
  \centering       % <============================
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a.jpg}  
  \captionof{figure}{Caption text}
} 

 aeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo iaeoiaeo aeo eaoiaeoiaeoi oiaeo iaeoiaeo 

 \end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Please have a look to question [when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering) to see the difference between environment `center` and macro `\centering`.

Comment: Thank you! The MWE works as expected but if I copy the code to my project, I get the same error "Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }". See the edit

Comment: How can I have too many brackets if the file compiles fine and I only pasted the \marginpar snipped?