# How to place an image in the left margin of a title page

Tags: graphics, margins, covers

I have to make a book cover for my document which must have a png image covering all the height of the left page margin. The rest of the page must have pictures, and text lines centered.

Something like the following coverpage:

[image]

How could I do it?

All I can get is to fill with a color the left side of the page

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw [fill,red!20] (current page.north west) rectangle +(0.33\paperwidth,-\paperheight);%
Rather Long Document Title to Show that the Colour is Behind the Title}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

but not to insert an image.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show what you've got so far (MWE) and it would be great if you could provide us with a picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Does the following help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136543/124842

Comment: Your code is still not a [minimal *but working* example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Please help us helping you.