# Error on table inside a beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm preparing a presentation using the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class, and I need to put a tabular environment inside it and I always get the errors

> Undefined control sequence `\end{frame}`

and

> Missing number, treated as zero `\end{frame}`

The document is not compiling.

I'm kinda new to LaTeX and I keep all my packages from document to document, I forgot what are some for.
Do you have an idea what is happening?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xlop} %opérations de beau gosse
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen} %probablement fullscreen at launch
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,165,50} %creer une couleur
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=black}
\usecolortheme[named=color1]{structure} %utiliser une couleur
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\theoremstyle{definition} %pour des boites a théorèmes
\newtheorem*{dfn}{Définition}       

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{rotating}


%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{0.1cm}\null\vspace{0.05cm}} %numéro des diapos

\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[H]
\doublespacing
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}

\hline
\textbf{Wear mechanisms} & \textbf{Applications} & \textbf{Deposited materials} & \textbf{Deposition processes}\\
\hline
Abrasive wear & Pump shafts & Cr-Co & HOVF, plasma, detonation\\
\hline
Adhesive wear & Pistons, brakes & Mo, Ni-Cr, Cu-Ni-In & Plasma, flame, HOVF\\
\hline
Contact wear & Aircraft leading edge & Tungsten carbide, Co & Detonation HVOF\\
\hline
Erosion & Power plant fan & Tungsten carbide, $\textnormal{Al}_{2}\textnormal{O}_{3}$, $\textnormal{Cr}_{2}\textnormal{O}_{3}$ & Detonation, HVOF\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{Examples of thermal sprayed coatings against wear}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It will be easy to help you if you provide us with a complete example, starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}`. It should include all packages and styles you need to reproduce the problem which is different from all packages and styles you use in your complete document.

Comment: All packages used is the document added to the code.

Comment: Comment out `\doublespacing` and your code will compile.

Comment: You surely don't need all those packages to reproduce your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please note that it's recommended to use `\centering` inside a `figure` environment instead of the `center` environment. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering for more details.

Comment: Getting rid of \doublespacing worked, but how can I make them wider without this ?

Comment: If you want `\doublespacing` to produce taller rows, another option would be to include `\rule{0pt}{4ex}` in any cell but in every row.

Comment: I'm sure some of those packages will disagree with beamer and there is no need to load graphicx twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you, the problem with your code was command `\doublespacing`. Commenting it out, your code will compile without problems. You wanted it to "wider" table spacing. If this means a larger distance between tabular text and separation lines you have several alternatives. One of them consists in fixing `\extrarowheight` from [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) package. Next code (taken from "The LaTeX Companion, 2ed") shows how to use it and its effects on rows height.

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\large}c|>{\large\bfseries}l|>{\itshape}c|}
\hline A & B & C\\\hline 100 & 10 & 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\large}c|>{\large\bfseries}l|>{\itshape}c|}
\hline A & B & C\\\hline 100 & 10 & 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

In any case I prefer to use [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and its `\top-\mid-\bottomrule` commands. I think results are good enough without any other adjustments.

Next code shows an example typesetting your table inside a `beamer` frame. I've made some adjustments to fit all table in one frame.

1. Used `\small` to reduce font size
2. Used `array` package for `>{decl}` and center cell text
3. Used `p{column width}` cell types
4. Used `booktabs` package

The complete code is

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usetheme{Berkeley}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,165,50} %creer une couleur
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=black}
\usecolortheme[named=color1]{structure} %utiliser une couleur
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

%\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace{0.1cm}\null\vspace{0.05cm}} %numéro des diapos

%\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering

{\small\begin{tabular}{%
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{.2\textwidth}
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{.2\textwidth}
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{.2\textwidth}
    >{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{.2\textwidth}}

\toprule
\textbf{Wear mechanisms} & \textbf{Applications} & \textbf{Deposited materials} & \textbf{Deposition processes}\tabularnewline
\midrule
Abrasive wear & Pump shafts & Cr-Co & HOVF, plasma, detonation\tabularnewline
\midrule
Adhesive wear & Pistons, brakes & Mo, Ni-Cr, Cu-Ni-In & Plasma, flame, HOVF\tabularnewline
\midrule
Contact wear & Aircraft leading edge & Tungsten carbide, Co & Detonation HVOF\tabularnewline
\midrule
Erosion & Power plant fan & Tungsten carbide, $\textnormal{Al}_{2}\textnormal{O}_{3}$, $\textnormal{Cr}_{2}\textnormal{O}_{3}$ & Detonation, HVOF\tabularnewline
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}}
\caption{Examples of thermal sprayed coatings against wear}

\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\large}c|>{\large\bfseries}l|>{\itshape}c|}
\hline A & B & C\\\hline 100 & 10 & 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\large}c|>{\large\bfseries}l|>{\itshape}c|}
\hline A & B & C\\\hline 100 & 10 & 1\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The final result is

[image]