# Why does putting a vspace*{0 mm} create vertical spacing?

Tags: spacing

I am testing a new layout for my invoice. I am trying to put some small vertical spacing before the invoice title. While tesing the vertical spacing, I have spotted a strange behaviour, and reduced it to 0 just to see what happens:

```
\begin{document}

\vspace*{0 mm}

{\LARGE\center <<title>>\\}

\vspace{10 mm}

...
```

And this produces a different layout than:

```
\begin{document}

{\LARGE\center <<title>>\\}

\vspace{10 mm}

...
```

In the first case, there is substantial vertical space (even though I am setting i to 0 mm), and in the second one there is none. Why?

Comment: Your are (wrongly) using the command `\center` which actually starts the center environment, which is a list. `\vspace*{}` puts an invisible box on the page and so the space before this list is no longer discarded at the start of a page. Better use `{\LARGE\centering Title \par}`.

Answer (score 12):

The following examples are using `\centering` instead of environment `center`, see question ["When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/16967) for details.

`\showlists` can be used to analyze the spacing:

```
% configuring, how much is shown by `\showlists` or `\showbox`
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \vspace*{0mm}

  {\LARGE\centering Title}

  \showlists
\end{document}
```

Result:

> ```
> ### vertical mode entered at line 0
> ### current page:
> \write-{}
> \glue(\topskip) 10.0
> \rule(0.0+0.0)x*
> \penalty 10000
> \glue 0.0
> \glue 0.0
> \glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
> \glue(\baselineskip) 0.0
> \hbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 311.69482fil
> .\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 T
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 i
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 t
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 l
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 e
> .\penalty 10000
> .\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> .\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
> total height 22.0 plus 1.0
>  goal height 550.0
> prevdepth 0.0, prevgraf 1 line
> ```

Thus the page contains as additional white space elements before the title:

- `\topskip`, it is a parameter that helps to align the first lines on the pages. It is only automatically added at the top of the page. On this page, however, there is not a "first line" to align. Thus it can be set to zero.
- `\parskip`, here `0pt plus 1pt`, but it might be different.
- `\baselineskip`, here `0pt`, because the next line is over large (`\LARGE`).

The following example avoids these white spaces:

```
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \begingroup
    \setlength{\topskip}{0mm}% \topskip is set to zero
    \vspace*{0mm}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}% \parskip is set to zero
    \nointerlineskip % avoids addition of \baselineskip before next line
    \centering
    \LARGE
    Title
    \par
  \endgroup

  \showlists

\end{document}
```

Result:

> ```
> ### vertical mode entered at line 0
> ### current page:
> \write-{}
> \glue(\topskip) 0.0
> \rule(0.0+0.0)x*
> \penalty 10000
> \glue 0.0
> \glue 0.0
> \glue(\parskip) 0.0
> \hbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 155.84741fil
> .\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> .\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 T
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 i
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 t
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 l
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/17.28 e
> .\penalty 10000
> .\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
> .\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
> total height 12.0
>  goal height 550.0
> prevdepth 0.0, prevgraf 1 line
> ```

Thus the title hits the top of the text area. It can be visualized by option `showframe` of package geometry:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  showframe,
  % smaller image for answer in TeX.SX
  paperwidth=5cm,
  paperheight=5cm,
  margin=5mm,
  includeheadfoot,
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begingroup
    \setlength{\topskip}{0mm}%
    \vspace*{0mm}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \centering
    \LARGE
    Title
    \par
  \endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: An excellent answer!