# Too much space below figures

Tags: spacing, graphics

I am trying to use `graphicx` package to include figures. However it seems to leave 
too much space between the figure and caption.

My LaTeX lines are

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{1hamlabels.eps}
\end{center}
```

Is there any way to reduce this space while using `graphicx` package? I dont wanna use tikz or anythin like that.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `center` environment is the culprit of the vertical space. You only want to insert your figures without inserting them in a `figure` environment?

Comment: See [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

Answer (score 4):

You can add some vertical negative space before `\end{center}`, e.g.

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{1hamlabels.eps}
\vspace*{-5pt}
\end{center}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the option demo in your document

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{1hamlabels.eps}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{1hamlabels.eps}
\vspace*{-5pt}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]   

\end{document}
```

Output (you can notice the difference: the left page has not this correction)

[image]