# How to center the table in Latex

Tags: tables

I have got a simple code to generate table in Latex.

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline
  symbol & value & unit \\ \hline            
  $z Na$ & 11 & - \\ \hline      
  $z F$ & 9 & - \\ \hline      
  $Emax Na$ & 0.545 & $[MeV]$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This code is good, but I would like to add this table to my document in Latex and have this table centered. The point is that table would be in the middle not on the left nor on the right but in the middle. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
\{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline
  symbol & value & unit \\ \hline            
  $z Na$ & 11 & - \\ \hline      
  $z F$ & 9 & - \\ \hline      
  $Emax Na$ & 0.545 & $[MeV]$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\{\center}
```

I appreciate the answer.

Comment: You need `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` rather than `\{center} .. \{\center}`.

Answer (score 179):

You can just add `\centering` right after `\begin{table}` to center the table:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As commented by @PeterGrill,  if you are not using floats (i.e., `\begin{table}`, `\end{table}`), then you will need to group it:

```
{
\centering
\begin{tabular} 
... 
\end{tabular}\par
}
```

Note that \par and the extra `{}`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work:

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \centering
  \hline
  symbol & value & unit \\ \hline            
  $z Na$ & 11 & - \\ \hline      
  $z F$ & 9 & - \\ \hline      
  $Emax Na$ & 0.545 & $[MeV]$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

Comment: The `\centering` should be _outside_ of `\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}`. If you are not using floats (i.e., `\begin{table}`, `\end{table}`), then you will need to group it: `{\centering\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}}` (note the extra `{}`).

Comment: @PeterGrill Good point. Added to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The second option does not appear to work. I would like to include a `tabular` environment without using floats, but centering it.

Comment: If the second option doesn't work for you, try `\begin{center} \end{center}` instead of `{ }` as mentioned in @Walton's answer.

Comment: this does not work for me with \begin{table}[!ht] 
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{6in} the table still starts at the same x position on the page and then travels off the page

Comment: Personally, this doesn't work for me. The centering just doesn't happen. Walton's answer worked for me.

Comment: This does not work if the table is wider than the space (e.g. the column of the page). In that case, it is not centered, but left aligned. I think this was possible to center via `resizebox` or `adjustbox` or so. I use `\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.\width,center} ...`. [See also](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174566/center-a-table-that-uses-resizebox).

Comment: `{\centering ...}` doesn't work for me either, it doesn't center the table - and my table is not very wide.

Comment: You **must** use `\par` before closing the group with `}`. [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/41320)
So, it'll be `{\centering \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular} \par }`

Answer (score 49):

You can also use `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. This works better with `beamer` for example because `{\centering ... }` messes with the size of the table for some reason. The new code would be:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
  \hline
  symbol & value & unit \\ \hline
  $z Na$ & 11 & - \\ \hline
  $z F$ & 9 & - \\ \hline
  $Emax Na$ & 0.545 & $[MeV]$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

More on the difference between `\begin{center}` and `\centering`:
[When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: The OP does not mention `beamer` at all? Why do you think that `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is better?

Comment: I brought up beamer as an example of a difference I noticed. I don't necessarily think it's better for this situation, but no one has mentioned it as an option yet.

Comment: `{\centering ... }` doesn't center the table for me - and `\begin{center}...\end{center}` adds a huge margin around the top/bottom of the table.