# center a table that uses resizebox

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, scaling

I create a table that I would like centered on the page horizontally. I scale the table size using `\resizebox`. However, doing so, left aligns the table. How do I center it?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{mytable}
    \resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{

    \begin{centering}
        \begin{tabular}{rrr}
            A                     & B                  & C \\
            \hline
            A1                   & B1             &C1\\
            A2                  & B2                  & C2 \\
            A3                    & B3             & C3 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{centering}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no `centering` environment. And issuing `\centering` inside `\resizebox` doesn't make sense anyway: it should be outside, because you want to center the resized box.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{mytable}
\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{% <------ Don't forget this %
  \begin{tabular}{rrr}
  A              & B            & C \\
  \hline
  A1             & B1           & C1 \\
  A2             & B2           & C2 \\
  A3             & B3           & C3 \\
  \end{tabular}% <------ Don't forget this %
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: why do you need the % there?

Comment: @Alex Without them you'd get spaces on either side of the table

Comment: @egreg, how do you do if not within a table environment? Using just {\centering .... } as discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162462/how-to-center-the-table-in-latex does not seem to work? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou while there is no `centering` environment, there is a `center` environment. That can definitely center a resized box.

Answer (score 5):

Here an alternative answer using `adjustbox`. It covers the functionality of `\resizebox` and is also able to center its content. It also removes the need of escaping the line breaks with `%` as seen in egregs answer, as the `adjustbox` environment removes the  spaces added by them.

It is even possible to produce the `table` environment using `adjustbox` keys, or even to get the whole `tabular` environment replaced. This saves you a lot of typing in the long run. Note that the order of most `adjustbox` keys matter.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{mytable}% will not give you proper skip as it is configured for placement below the content
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.5\textwidth,center}
  \begin{tabular}{rrr}
  A              & B            & C \\
  \hline
  A1             & B1           & C1 \\
  A2             & B2           & C2 \\
  A3             & B3           & C3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

% shorter, also covering the `table` environment
\begin{adjustbox}{width=.5\textwidth,center,caption=mytable,float=table}
  \begin{tabular}{rrr}
  A              & B            & C \\
  \hline
  A1             & B1           & C1 \\
  A2             & B2           & C2 \\
  A3             & B3           & C3 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

% even shorter, now also covering the `tabular` environment
\begin{adjustbox}{tabular=rrr,width=.5\textwidth,center,caption=mytable,float=table}
  A              & B            & C \\
  \hline
  A1             & B1           & C1 \\
  A2             & B2           & C2 \\
  A3             & B3           & C3 \\
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to use `\width` instead of `\textwidth` for a 2 column page.

Comment: @Albert: Try `\columnwidth` in that case. Using `0.5\width` makes it half the original size, which might just work or not.

Comment: Or maybe `\linewidth`?

Comment: @Albert: Yes, `\linewidth` is a good option as well.