# Table not centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center a table but it is not formatting well. I have looked at questions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162462/how-to-center-the-table-in-latex) but none of the answers there seem to solve my problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
    \hline
    Steps & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8 & Trial 9 & Trial 10 \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & -3 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
    4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & -4 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
    5 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 & 5 & 3 & -5 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
    6 & 2 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 6 & 4 & -6 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
    7 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 5 & 3 & -7 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    8 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 & -8 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\
    9 & 3 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 3 & 5 & -9 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    10 & 2 & 0 & -2 & -2 & 2 & 6 & -8 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    11 & 3 & -1 & -1 & -3 & 3 & 5 & -7 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    12 & 2 & -2 & -2 & -4 & 4 & 4 & -8 & -4 & 2 & 2 \\
    13 & 1 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & 5 & -9 & -3 & 3 & 3 \\
    14 & 2 & -2 & -4 & -2 & 4 & 4 & -10 & -2 & 4 & 2 \\
    15 & 1 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & 3 & -9 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\
    16 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -4 & 4 & 2 & -8 & -2 & 2 & 0 \\
    17 & 1 & -3 & -1 & -5 & 5 & 3 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -1 \\
    18 & 2 & -4 & -2 & -4 & 6 & 2 & -10 & -4 & 2 & -2 \\
    19 & 3 & -3 & -3 & -5 & 7 & 3 & -11 & -5 & 3 & -3 \\
    20 & 2 & -2 & -4 & -4 & 6 & 2 & -10 & -4 & 2 & -2 \\
    21 & 3 & -1 & -5 & -5 & 5 & 1 & -9 & -5 & 3 & -3 \\
    22 & 2 & -2 & -6 & -6 & 6 & 0 & -8 & -4 & 4 & -2 \\
    23 & 1 & -1 & -7 & -7 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -3 \\
    24 & 0 & 0 & -6 & -8 & 6 & -2 & -10 & -4 & 4 & -4 \\
    25 & 1 & -1 & -7 & -9 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -3 \\
    26 & 0 & -2 & -6 & -10 & 8 & -2 & -10 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
    27 & 1 & -3 & -7 & -11 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -1 & 5 & -3 \\
    28 & 0 & -2 & -6 & -10 & 6 & 0 & -8 & 0 & 4 & -4 \\
    29 & -1 & -1 & -7 & -11 & 5 & 1 & -7 & -1 & 3 & -3 \\
    30 & 0 & 0 & -8 & -12 & 4 & 2 & -6 & 0 & 2 & -4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I tried a lot of different styles to format this like `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` but none of them work properly.

In the end, the table looks like this [image: this]

What should I do to fix this issue

Comment: TeX/LaTeX can't center something that is just too wide. Each of your cells has a width of about 1.5cm, having 11 of them this means the table is about 17 cm wide, which is more than the usual `\textwidth` length (in your standard setting of  `article.cls`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use package called geometry to solved your table problem

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | }
           \hline
    Steps & Trial 1 & Trial 2 & Trial 3 & Trial 4 & Trial 5 & Trial 6 & Trial 7 & Trial 8 & Trial 9 & Trial 10 \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 3 & 1 & -3 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
    4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & -4 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
    5 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 & 5 & 3 & -5 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
    6 & 2 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 6 & 4 & -6 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
    7 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 5 & 3 & -7 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    8 & 2 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 4 & 4 & -8 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\
    9 & 3 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 3 & 5 & -9 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    10 & 2 & 0 & -2 & -2 & 2 & 6 & -8 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    11 & 3 & -1 & -1 & -3 & 3 & 5 & -7 & -3 & 1 & 1 \\
    12 & 2 & -2 & -2 & -4 & 4 & 4 & -8 & -4 & 2 & 2 \\
    13 & 1 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & 5 & -9 & -3 & 3 & 3 \\
    14 & 2 & -2 & -4 & -2 & 4 & 4 & -10 & -2 & 4 & 2 \\
    15 & 1 & -3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & 3 & -9 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\
    16 & 0 & -2 & -2 & -4 & 4 & 2 & -8 & -2 & 2 & 0 \\
    17 & 1 & -3 & -1 & -5 & 5 & 3 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -1 \\
    18 & 2 & -4 & -2 & -4 & 6 & 2 & -10 & -4 & 2 & -2 \\
    19 & 3 & -3 & -3 & -5 & 7 & 3 & -11 & -5 & 3 & -3 \\
    20 & 2 & -2 & -4 & -4 & 6 & 2 & -10 & -4 & 2 & -2 \\
    21 & 3 & -1 & -5 & -5 & 5 & 1 & -9 & -5 & 3 & -3 \\
    22 & 2 & -2 & -6 & -6 & 6 & 0 & -8 & -4 & 4 & -2 \\
    23 & 1 & -1 & -7 & -7 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -3 \\
    24 & 0 & 0 & -6 & -8 & 6 & -2 & -10 & -4 & 4 & -4 \\
    25 & 1 & -1 & -7 & -9 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -3 & 3 & -3 \\
    26 & 0 & -2 & -6 & -10 & 8 & -2 & -10 & -2 & 4 & -2 \\
    27 & 1 & -3 & -7 & -11 & 7 & -1 & -9 & -1 & 5 & -3 \\
    28 & 0 & -2 & -6 & -10 & 6 & 0 & -8 & 0 & 4 & -4 \\
    29 & -1 & -1 & -7 & -11 & 5 & 1 & -7 & -1 & 3 & -3 \\
    30 & 0 & 0 & -8 & -12 & 4 & 2 & -6 & 0 & 2 & -4 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `siunitx` and `booktabs` you can get a better result: precise alignment for digits and minus signs where appropriate.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
 @{}
 S[table-format=2.0]
 *{10}{S[table-format=-2.0]}
 @{}
}
\toprule
{Steps} &  \multicolumn{10}{c}{Trial} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-11}
   & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} &{10} \\
\midrule
 1 &   1 &   1 &  -1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &  -1 &  -1 &  -1 &   1 \\
 2 &   0 &   2 &   0 &   0 &   2 &   0 &  -2 &  -2 &  -2 &   0 \\
 3 &   1 &   1 &  -1 &   1 &   3 &   1 &  -3 &  -1 &  -3 &   1 \\
 4 &   0 &   0 &  -2 &   2 &   4 &   2 &  -4 &   0 &  -2 &   2 \\
 5 &   1 &  -1 &  -3 &   1 &   5 &   3 &  -5 &   1 &  -1 &   3 \\
 6 &   2 &  -2 &  -2 &   0 &   6 &   4 &  -6 &   0 &  -2 &   2 \\
 7 &   1 &  -1 &  -1 &  -1 &   5 &   3 &  -7 &  -1 &  -1 &   1 \\
 8 &   2 &   0 &   0 &  -2 &   4 &   4 &  -8 &  -2 &  -2 &   0 \\
 9 &   3 &  -1 &  -1 &  -1 &   3 &   5 &  -9 &  -1 &  -1 &   1 \\
10 &   2 &   0 &  -2 &  -2 &   2 &   6 &  -8 &  -2 &   0 &   0 \\
11 &   3 &  -1 &  -1 &  -3 &   3 &   5 &  -7 &  -3 &   1 &   1 \\
12 &   2 &  -2 &  -2 &  -4 &   4 &   4 &  -8 &  -4 &   2 &   2 \\
13 &   1 &  -3 &  -3 &  -3 &   3 &   5 &  -9 &  -3 &   3 &   3 \\
14 &   2 &  -2 &  -4 &  -2 &   4 &   4 & -10 &  -2 &   4 &   2 \\
15 &   1 &  -3 &  -3 &  -3 &   3 &   3 &  -9 &  -1 &   3 &   1 \\
16 &   0 &  -2 &  -2 &  -4 &   4 &   2 &  -8 &  -2 &   2 &   0 \\
17 &   1 &  -3 &  -1 &  -5 &   5 &   3 &  -9 &  -3 &   3 &  -1 \\
18 &   2 &  -4 &  -2 &  -4 &   6 &   2 & -10 &  -4 &   2 &  -2 \\
19 &   3 &  -3 &  -3 &  -5 &   7 &   3 & -11 &  -5 &   3 &  -3 \\
20 &   2 &  -2 &  -4 &  -4 &   6 &   2 & -10 &  -4 &   2 &  -2 \\
21 &   3 &  -1 &  -5 &  -5 &   5 &   1 &  -9 &  -5 &   3 &  -3 \\
22 &   2 &  -2 &  -6 &  -6 &   6 &   0 &  -8 &  -4 &   4 &  -2 \\
23 &   1 &  -1 &  -7 &  -7 &   7 &  -1 &  -9 &  -3 &   3 &  -3 \\
24 &   0 &   0 &  -6 &  -8 &   6 &  -2 & -10 &  -4 &   4 &  -4 \\
25 &   1 &  -1 &  -7 &  -9 &   7 &  -1 &  -9 &  -3 &   3 &  -3 \\
26 &   0 &  -2 &  -6 & -10 &   8 &  -2 & -10 &  -2 &   4 &  -2 \\
27 &   1 &  -3 &  -7 & -11 &   7 &  -1 &  -9 &  -1 &   5 &  -3 \\
28 &   0 &  -2 &  -6 & -10 &   6 &   0 &  -8 &   0 &   4 &  -4 \\
29 &  -1 &  -1 &  -7 & -11 &   5 &   1 &  -7 &  -1 &   3 &  -3 \\
30 &   0 &   0 &  -8 & -12 &   4 &   2 &  -6 &   0 &   2 &  -4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]