# tcolorbox spacing with \center environment and \centering switch

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, tcolorbox

In `LaTeX`, the way `\begin{center}....\end{center}` spaces the `tcolorbox` is different from how `\centering` does it. The `center` environment, provides enough space but the vertical spacing done with `\centering` isn't the same as with `center` environment. Now my question is, when using `\centering`, how do I achieve the same spacing of `tcolorbox` as done with `center` environment.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\unittcbox}[1]{%
\medskip \centering \tcbox{#1} \medskip
}%
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\unittcbox{SI unit :  Ampere. square metre ($A.m²$)}
\kant[2]
\begin{center}
\tcbox{SI unit :  Ampere. square metre ($A.m²$)}
\end{center}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

I tried with `\medskip` but it didn't workout.

Using centering:

[image]

Using center environment:

[image]

Comment: this is not really about tcolorbox, you should check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/24483 what you're looking for is the difference between center environment and `\centering`

Comment: No @dcmst, it didnt help me solve the problem. It says add a `\par`, tried it but no use :(

Comment: I mean the part where it says that `center` adds a `\trivlist`. See the definition of `\center`: `\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}` and `\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}`

Comment: `\centering` doesn't do any vertical spacing it just sets the paragraph alignment to center, the center environment does `\centering` but also adds vertical space. Your question isn't at all clear, but if you want the spacing of the center environment why not use that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this is what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newtcolorbox{units}{before=\par\smallskip\centering,after=\par,hbox}

\begin{document}
\kant*[2]
\begin{units}
SI unit :  Ampere. square metre (\si{A.m^2})
\end{units}
Some text comes here just for demo.
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have defined a new environment so that you don't have to type much every time.

If you want more space, you may use

```
\newtcolorbox{units}{before=\begin{center},after=\end{center},hbox}
```

or manually adjust the space as in

```
\newtcolorbox{units}{before=\par\bigskip\centering,after=\par\bigskip,hbox}
```

Comment: But, the spacing is a bit less I feel. Can it be increased to similar of \center enironment

Comment: @subhamsoni I have added the options.

Answer (score 5):

My impression is that you want to use the `on line` option:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant*[2]
\begin{center}
\tcbox[on line]{SI unit :  Ampere. square metre (\si{A.m^2})}
\end{center}
\kant[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit the code in such a that, it uses `\newcommand` as in my MWE