# getting rid of underfull Bad boxes

Tags: boxes

```
\begin{table}[h]
                \begin{center} 
                \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
                \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     **\multirow{3}*{{\bf Ingredients}} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{{\bf Composition of each kg of feed (gram)}} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{3.5cm}|}{{\bf Minimum monthly requirement per turkey (gram)}}\\\cline{2-3}**
      & {\bf Brand 1} & {\bf Brand 2} &   \\ \hline
     {\bf A} & 5 & 10 & 90  \\ 
     {\bf B} & 4 & 3 & 48  \\ 
     {\bf C} & 18 & 0 & 1 \\   
     {\bf Cost per kg} & 2c & 3c &  \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{table:one}Turkey Feed}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

---

```
underfull \hbox (badness 10000) Composition of
underfull \hbox (badness 2103) minimum monthly
underfull \hbox (badness 10000) requirement per
```

Please can you assist with these bad boxes.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: apart from the alignment issues don't use `[h]`  (latex normally warns about thatt and changes it to `[ht]` but `[htp]` is better) and `\bf` has been deprecated since latex2e was introduced in 1993)

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate them via adding `\RaggedRight` form the `ragged2e` package:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should use `\bfseries` instead of `\bf: [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)
- Also use `\centering` and the `center` environment: [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     **\multirow{3}*{{\bfseries Ingredients}} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{3cm}|}{\bfseries\RaggedRight Composition of each kg of feed (gram)} & \multicolumn{1}{|p{3.5cm}|}{\bfseries\RaggedRight Minimum monthly requirement per turkey (gram)}\\\cline{2-3}**
      & {\bfseries Brand 1} & {\bfseries Brand 2} &   \\ \hline
     {\bfseries A} & 5 & 10 & 90  \\ 
     {\bfseries B} & 4 & 3 & 48  \\ 
     {\bfseries C} & 18 & 0 & 1 \\   
     {\bfseries Cost per kg} & 2c & 3c &  \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{table:one}Turkey Feed}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```