# rotation problem text in arrow tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to make a graphic that needs two arrows, I've already found how to rotate the arrow, but I don't want the text to be rotated 180 degrees.

Bonusproblem, I want the red line ticker ...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc, trees, positioning, arrows, shapes, shapes.multipart, shadows, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 1/7/Y, 13/1/X, 1/2/B, 13/2/E, 7/2/K, 7/6.3/L, 4/5/J, 10/5/M, -2/2.5/C, 16/2.5/D}
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
\draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {stress (+)};
\draw[very thick, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(B) (J) (L) (M) (E)};
 \node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=blue!30, draw, align=center, xshift=3cm, yshift=2.5cm, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm]{Concentratie \\ Inspanning };
\node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=red!30, draw, align=center, xshift=11cm, yshift=2.5cm, rotate=180, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm]{Relaxatie \\ Ontspanning};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `rotate=180`, you can use `shape border rotate=180`.  To get a thicker red line you can apply `ultra thick` or even specify the exact thickness via `line width=<size>` (as I have done below).

[image]

But as you can see from the above, with a really thick red line the ends don't look so good, and the intersection with the vertical axis is not very nice. That can be fixed by using `line cap=round` and *whiting* out the overlap of the axis to obtain:

[image]

---

You can draw another line by applying a shift to each coordinate (not sure why a `scope` did not work though). And to make the desired arrows visible, I added a `shorten >=-0.4cm` so that the arrows of the lines are not obscured by large rotated arrow.

[image]

### Notes:

- I also replaced the `center` environment with `\centering` so as to eliminate the vertical space as per [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc, trees, positioning, arrows, shapes, shapes.multipart, shadows, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 1/7/Y, 13/1/X, 1/2/B, 13/2/E, 7/2/K, 7/6.3/L, 4/5/J, 10/5/M, -2/2.5/C, 16/2.5/D}


\draw[line width=5pt, line cap=round, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(B) (J) (L) (M) (E)};
 \node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=blue!30, draw, align=center, xshift=3cm, yshift=2.5cm, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm]{Concentratie \\ Inspanning };
\node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=red!30, draw, align=center, xshift=11cm, yshift=2.5cm, shape border rotate=180, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm, ]{Relaxatie \\ Ontspanning};

%% Fill out the overflow of the really thick red line
\fill[white] (A) rectangle ($(A)+(-3.0em,2.0cm)$);

%% Move to be after so that the axis is on top of the thick red line
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
\draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {stress (+)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Second Line & Arrows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc, trees, positioning, arrows, shapes, shapes.multipart, shadows, matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{My Shift/.style={yshift=0.75cm}}

\begin{document}
{\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A, 1/7/Y, 13/1/X, 1/2/B, 13/2/E, 7/2/K, 7/6.3/L, 4/5/J, 10/5/M, -2/2.5/C, 16/2.5/D}


\draw[line width=5pt, line cap=round, red, -latex, shorten >=-0.4cm] plot [smooth] coordinates {(B) (J) (L) (M) (E)};
\draw[line width=5pt, line cap=round, blue, -latex, shorten >=-0.4cm] plot [smooth] coordinates {([My Shift]B) ([My Shift]J) ([My Shift]L) ([My Shift]M) ([My Shift]E)};


\node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=blue!30, draw, align=center, xshift=3cm, yshift=2.5cm, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm]{Concentratie \\ Inspanning };

\node[single arrow, rounded corners=3pt, fill=red!30, draw, align=center, xshift=11cm, yshift=2.5cm, shape border rotate=180, minimum height=4cm, minimum width=2cm, ]{Relaxatie \\ Ontspanning};

%% Fill out the overflow of the really thick red line
\fill[white] (A) rectangle ($(A)+(-3.0em,2.0cm)$);

%% Move to be after so that the axis is on top of the thick red line
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
\draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {stress (+)};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the smooth ending of the line. In fact I want to end it with an arrow. And make the same line in blue 3mm above the red one...

Comment: @Arne: Posted revised solution with another parallel line and arrows.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it with "y-shifting" the curve in total, and that didn't work. But this is perfect. Thanks!