# 5 Figures arranged in 3 rows x 2 columns

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I would like to arrange 5 figures in 3 x 2 format. I would like the figures to look like this:

[image]

I tried the following (See below) but cannot get the 2 figures in the second row to be centered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{lll}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{rr}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: They are centered!!  Add `usepackage{showframe}` and you will see that the page is not wide enough. The second line _is_ centered within the `\linewidth`.  Also, you should use `centering` instead of the `center` environment as per [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's much simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\medskip

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

About your code. First of all, you probably don't have 150mm available, plus the intercolumn space. By using `.3\textwidth` we know that we'll occupy 9/10 of the allotted width.

Second. Instead of `$\begin{array}...\end{array}$` you could use `tabular`: same syntax, but goes in text mode (and can even go in math mode). But two tabulars are not what's needed: just center the two rows and you're done, just remember to leave some space (here a `\quad`) between two images. A vertical space between the rows, *et voilà*. `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use subcaptions to distinguish between the figures, you can use the following code:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c} \\
\textbf{(a)}  & \textbf{(b)} & \textbf{(c)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b} \\
\textbf{(d)}  & \textbf{(e)}  \\[6pt]
\end{tabular}
\caption{ \textbf{(a)} Some text
\textbf{(b)} Some text
\textbf{(c)} Some text
\textbf{(d)} Some text
\textbf{(e)} Some text}
\label{fig:Name}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The code you provided does indeed *center* them as you desire. Its just that the page is not wide enough. If I add `\usepackage[paperwidth=25.0cm,showframe]{geometry}` then you get:

[image]

Furthermore, you don't need to use the `array` environment as you don't have math content, simple `tabular` will suffice.  Also, you should use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment as per [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

### Notes:

- The `[showframe]` option was applied to [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry)
  was just to show the page margins.
- The `@{}` at the start and end of the `tabular` columns eliminates the column padding that is added at the start and end of the table.
- The `tabular` solution is useful if you want the figures horizontally aligned. If you don't need to align the figures (ie., you just want them distributed horizontally), the Werner's or egreg's solution is the way to go.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=25.0cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{lll}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{rr}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `\centering`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=25.0cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
{\centering%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}\par}

{\centering%
\begin{tabular}{@{}rr@{}}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image-b}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}\par}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\caption` is not affected by `\centering`, so you just need one `\centering` command. But why a `tabular`?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for such distributions is provided by `tcolorbox` with `tcbraster` environments. In this case option `raster halign=center` ensures that last line boxes are centered on their line.

Following code shows two examples, the first one just places the images without any subcaption, while the second one uses `subfig` package to allow adding particular captions to each subfigure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subfig} %For subcaptions

\newcommand{\mysubfig}[3][width=\linewidth]{%
    \tcbitem\subfloat[#2]{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcbraster}[
    raster columns=3,
    raster halign=center,
    raster every box/.style={blankest},
    ]
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
\end{tcbraster}

\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcbitemize}[
    raster columns=3,
    raster halign=center,
    raster every box/.style={blankest}
    ]
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\mysubfig{}{example-image-b}
\end{tcbitemize}

\caption{Figure caption}
\label{pics:blablabla}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]