# Runaway argument in table, tabular

Tags: floats

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H!]
   \begin{center}
       \caption{Blah blah blah}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
           \hline
            & Training & Validation & Testing \\
            \hline
            Normal & 9727 & 194 & 605\\
            \hline
            Dos & 3128 & 782 & 2298\\
            \hline
            Prob & 320 & 82 & 41\\
            \hline
            R2L & 4 & 1 & 7\\
           \hline
           U2R & 5 & 7 &4 \\
           \hline
       \end{tabular}
    \end{center}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{table}[H!] \begin {center} \caption {Dataset size used in  experiment\ETC.
Paragraph ended before \@float@HH was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.298
```

Any ideas? I seem to be missing the point.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: If I was going to guess at the solution, it'd be that `[H!]` isn't a standard placement. Perhaps the example you started from uses an additional package like [float](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: you can't end paragraph in `\caption`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`H` is a very special float placement specifier in the sense that it changes the traditional float into a non-float. Therefore, it would be completely strange to suggest a float specification that includes both suggested locations (like `h`, `t`, `b`, ...) *together* with a forced non-float `H`; that is, use something of the form

```
\begin{table}[htH]
  ...
\end{table}
```

say, since there's no precedence/consideration between "the traditional specifiers" and `H`. The same goes for `!` (one of the force-suggested float specifiers).

So, use *only*

```
\begin{table}[H]
  ...
\end{table}
```

Internally [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) redefines the traditional float macros specifically to look for an `[H]` specifier. This search is *very* specific - `[H]` *only* and nothing else. Anything else and it would revert to the original float specifications. Read about this in the [`float` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) (section **4.2 Adapting LaTeX internals**).

Also read up on [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)

Comment: You're missing the correct answer: “don't use `[H]`.

Comment: I like `[H]`. It helps me put the objects I create exactly where I want them...

Answer (score 0):

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Blah blah blah}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & Training & Validation & Testing \\
            \hline
            Normal & 9727 & 194 & 605\\
            \hline
            Dos & 3128 & 782 & 2298\\
            \hline
            Prob & 320 & 82 & 41\\
            \hline
            R2L & 4 & 1 & 7\\
            \hline
            U2R & 5 & 7 &4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}    
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

The statement is for5, c values and you have given just 4 c values. This may be the error. Now it works well. I have removed many packages which you can add. I do not have them.