# Why does the header ruler jump down a line when I center header text?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I was trying to customize my header by using `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, however it results in the header ruler skipping a line and ending up in text.

How can I make it stay right underneath the header?

If you remove the `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` from the `\makeoddhead` command in the minimal example below, you can see where the header ruler is supposed to be.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,oneside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=3cm,textwidth=15cm,textheight=23cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setheadfoot{1cm}{1.5cm}

\makepagestyle{HDR}
\makepsmarks{HDR}{\nouppercaseheads 
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{\space}
    \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{\space} 
} 
\makeoddhead{HDR}{\begin{center}\small\normalfont\mdseries\textsc{\leftmark}\hskip.3cm\vrule\hskip.3cm\bfseries\rightmark\end{center}}{}{}
\makeheadrule{HDR}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{HDR}
\OnehalfSpacing

\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum
\section{Section Title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop the `center` environment. Simply put your definition into the next argument (currently empty) which is used for the center position. Like this: `\makeoddhead{HDR}{}{\small\normalfont\mdseries\textsc{\leftmark}\hskip.3cm\vrule\hskip.3cm\bfseries\rightmark}{}`

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I get for not taking the time to fully understand the commands I use. :0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `center` environment adds spacing around itself, which is not wanted inside a header. You can see more details at [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

From `texdoc memoir`, we can look for the documentation of the `\makeoddhead` command, which says this:

```
\makeoddhead{ <style> }{ <left> }{ <center> }{ <right> }
```

So, for centered header content, use the third argument instead of the second:

```
\makeoddhead{HDR}{}{\small\normalfont\mdseries\textsc{\leftmark}\hskip.3cm\vrule\hskip.3cm\bfseries\rightmark}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, you might want to rethink your code for the header here: things look a little unbalanced on the beginning pages of a chapter, where no `\section` has yet been issued.