# Why doesn't \par end this \centering?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, grouping

As per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/9077), `\par` should properly end the effect of `\centering`. But in the following case, it doesn't. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\@mytitle{} % create macro for title
    \newcommand\mytitle[1]{\renewcommand\@mytitle{#1}}
    \newcommand\@myauthor{} % create macro for author
    \newcommand\myauthor[1]{\renewcommand\@myauthor{#1}}
    \newcommand{\articletitle}{%
        \centering%
        \fontsize{18bp}{18bp}\selectfont%
        \@mytitle\par%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}%
        \fontsize{14bp}{14bp}\selectfont%
        \@myauthor\par%
        \fontsize{12bp}{12bp}\selectfont%
        \vspace{2\baselineskip}\par}%
\makeatother

\mytitle{This is my title}
\myauthor{This is the author}

\AtBeginDocument{\articletitle}

\begin{document}
I start writing here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A good example where *none but one* of the `%` at line endings serves no purpose whatsoever! `;-)` (Except for those introducing a comment, of course.)

Comment: @egreg I think you mean none but one serves *any* purpose i.e. only one serves a purpose. What you've said means that they all serve a purpose excepting one, which serves no purpose.

Comment: @egreg But, if you put it into informal Welsh, it will mean what you think ;).

Comment: @egreg I just developed the habit of putting `%` at the end of every line just in case, as I didn't really have a good understanding of when it was needed or not. I understand more now, but not enough that I dare ridding myself of this habit `:)`

Comment: @Sverre Look at my talk at the TUG meeting, paying particular attention to the “missing required space syndrome”. `;-)` http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/conferences/tug-2015

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\par` does *not* end the effect of `\centering`, the end of the paragraph is just the place, where TeX *uses* the values set by `\centering`. A group can be used to limit the effect of `\centering`. After the group, the settings before the group are in force again.

```
\begingroup
  \centering
  ...
  \par
\endgroup
```

or `{\centering ...\par}`.

Comment: Ok, but since my macro `\articletitle` has `{\centering ... \par ... \par ... \par}`, why is the whole document centered?

Comment: Nevermind - I understand now.

Comment: @Sverre The curly braces are *not* a group here, but they fence the definition text. Use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, the clearest version, or additional curly braces, if the number of key strokes matter more.

Answer (score 3):

...to further elaborate on [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263881/5764):

A macro provides a means to match some parameter text - this includes the actual macro and it's arguments or "delimiters" - gobbles these up, and replace them with the macro's replacement text - everything inside the outer `{`..`}`. This is informally referred to as expansion, where the input stream finds some macro, and expands or replaces it with something else.

In the case of your example, `\articletitle` has the following generic form:

```
\newcommand{\articletitle}{\centering <stuff>}
```

With the idea of replacement, every `\articletitle` is purely replaced by `\centering <stuff>` (everything inside the outer `{`...`}`). Note that while it seems `\centering` is contained within some scope inside the macro definition, the replacement text is void of such scope. If, however, you defined

```
\newcommand{\articletitle}{{\centering <stuff>}}
```

the replacement text would be `{\centering <stuff>}` where the limited scope (or group) follows the macro replacement text.

So, in order to limit the scope of a switch or declaration (like `\centering`) inside a macro, ensure that you include the necessary grouping `{`...`}` (or similar).