Justify switch after centering switch
What is the switch to return to fully justified text after a \centering or \raggedright switch? The expected justify or justifying are not it. Looking for the default latex solution with no extra packages needed. Not looking for a solution using groups.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1]

\centering

\lipsum[2-3]

% \justifying % what goes here to return to default justified text?

\lipsum[4-5]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}


See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263880/why-doesnt-par-end-this-centering and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723411/justify-switch-after-centering-switch

The standard LaTeX method is to segregate the special parts in an environment or as the argument to a comm
For instance, a well-written document should never have \normalfont in the document environment. If you switch to, say, italics, you don't want to “go back to the previous font”, which you have actually no control of unless you pedantically specify every time what the current font should be.
LaTeX lacks a command to “return to justifying text”, because it would be useless. Suppose you want to submit your paper to a journal; for your good reasons, you want that some text is typeset centered. If, after \centering you issue a  \JUSTIFYING command, the copy editors will be vary annoyed, because the standard setup for the journal is to typeset normal text ragged right.
So the solution is to use a command or an environment. If you don't want the additional vertical space added by center, define your own environment.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{centertext}{\par\centering\itshape}{\par\@endpetrue}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{centertext}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{centertext}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{centertext}
\lipsum[7][1-4]
\end{centertext}

\lipsum[6][1-3]

\end{document}

I added \itshape in order to better show the parts that are typeset with centering. But not only that: using an environment allows for doing many choices about your text. You may decide to add vertical space, for instance. Or you may want to remove \@endpetrue. What does it do?
It's a LaTeX internal: when an environment ends and \if@endpe is set to true, a blank line after the \end{<env>} command would add a normal indent, whereas no blank line will start a paragraph with no indentation (it's used in lists). You can indeed see that the text following the first centertext isn't indented, whereas in the other case the next paragraph is indented.


Is there really no switch to way to simply return to whatever the default is? I see your point for not wanting to specify justified as a hard rule.

@Bob The problem is that you can't know what the “default” is: grouping ensures you return to the previous state, which may or may not be, in this case, justified text.

Ah I see. Thanks for your help, I will just have to do it the right way. I admit I was expecting this answer but I was dumbfounded as to that I couldnt google my way to a solution.

You could use \justifying from the ragged2e package, but I would say you should never need to do that, it is almost a sign of a markup error.
use

{\centering

at the start and

}

at the end of the centered region. Note the blank line (\par) are required before the \centering and  before the close group so that the centering is properly applied to completed paragraphs.
Or (more normally) use
\begin{center}

and
\end{center}

but that gives additional vertical space.

latex does not provide a command to do this without using groups as it should  never be needed, if for some reason you don't want to use a package you could of course copy the definition of \justifying from ragged2e and add it to your document.

+1. I would add that  the "but" of   group \centering  is that the command behavior could be a bit odd at first. Ass \centering apply   to the current paragraph (even before the group) but should "see" the end of paragraph inside the group, the place of  blank lines (=\par)  before-after-inside the group matter very much: foo\par{\centering bar}\par is wrong, as  well as  foo{\centering bar}\par and foo {\centering bar\par}. Only  foo\par{\centering bar\par} will center   "bar" without center "foo". Complicated? No, it's just a lack of habit!

@Fran well yes, the blank line before } in the code shown here is intentional, and needed. (I'll add one to the start fragment as well though)

I know that it was  intentional, but I added  the comment because for new users a  blank line in the code could be  like the vacuum in the space: some that apparently does anything. It takes time learn  that the vacuum is really dark matter and dark energy. Well, "blank energy" in this case :)

I'll add a line to the answer:-) @Fran

For the sake of having fun beginners might be interested in comparing
text text \par {\centering foo \\ bar \\ baz \par} text text and
text text \par {foo \\ \centering bar \\ baz \par} text text and
text text \par {foo \\ bar \\ \centering baz \par} text text and
text text \par {foo \\ bar \\ baz \centering \par} text text.

What is one supposed to do if the standard setting is to typeset text ragged right or centered and for some good reason one wants some paragraph to be justified (and with \parindent) ?. ;-)

Thank you for your insight David.
