# Shiny - Package array Error: Illegal pream-token-

Tags: tables

I have the following table that is compiling when I use TeXnicCentre (running on MiKTeX):

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}
\Large{\textcolor{Gray}{DATE:}}& \\
\Large{\textcolor{Gray}{COUNTRIES:}}& \\
\Large{\textcolor{Gray}{DEVICES:}}& \\
\Large{\textcolor{Gray}{CHANNELS:}}& \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

However, I am trying to create reporting tool that compiles the PDF using Shiny R and I end up with the following error:

```
Running 'texi2dvi' on 'pdf_shell.tex' failed.
LaTeX errors:
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\textwidth): `c' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.136 \Large{\textcolor{Gray}{DATE:}}&
                                       \\
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.138 \Large{\textcolor{Gray}{COUNTRIES:}}&
                                            \\
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.140 \Large{\textcolor{Gray}{DEVICES:}}&
                                          \\
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.142 \Large{\textcolor{Gray}{CHANNELS:}}&
                                           \\
```

As far as I am concerned it might be related to the fact that I am using TeXnicCentre and shiny.io is running `texlive-xetex` and `texlive-latex-recommended` version 2009-15 for Ubuntu 12.04.

Does anyone have an idea how I could make my simple table work within the Shiny R, so it would be possible to create it on their TeX Live version?

Maybe I am wrong and something else is causing the problem.

Comment: The wrong code `\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}` will raise an error with *every* attempt at compilation.

Comment: Thank you, deleting `tabular` line actually solves my stupid mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `tabular` is

```
\begin{tabular}[<pos>]{<col spec>}
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular}
```

where `[<pos>]` (optional) denotes a vertical alignment `pos`ition or anchor. Options are `[t]`op, `[c]`entre (default) or `[b]`ottom. `<col spec>` (mandatory) defines a `spec`ification of the `col`umns.

Your usage

```
\begin{tabular}{<width>}
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular}
```

uses `<width>` instead of `<col spec>` results in the error as LaTeX expects something like `l`, `c`, `r` or `|`.

It seems like you're using a two-column `tabular`, so you're probably after

```
\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular}
```

---

The syntax for `tabular*` is similar, but includes a width specification:

```
\begin{tabular*}{<width>}[<pos>]{<col spec>}
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: Also rather use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` (see [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)). And, `\Large` doesn't take an argument. It's a font switch, so there's no need for `\Large{...}`, just `\Large` or `{\Large ...}`.