# LaTEX cannot ref figures. using texstudio as editor

Tags: cross-referencing

I hav the following figure:

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{image/a.pdf}
            \caption{a}
        \end{center}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{figure}
```

And call it somewhere in the middle of a text:

```
\ref{fig:a}
```

The output in pdf is only seen as:

```
Figure ??
```

What I must change?

Edit: I shifted the command `\lable{fig:a}` up:

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]

        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{image/a.pdf}
            \caption{a}
            \label{fig:a}
        \end{center}

    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Have you compiled 2 times?

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` better use `\centering` as the former introduces additional spacing.

Comment: See [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)

Comment: Apart from the `\begin{center}....\end{center}` issue inside the float: The label must appear in the same group. Outside of `\end{center}` it will use the wrong `\@currentlabel` macro, which is 'only' a `\protected@edef` macro, so known in the current group only, i.e. the` \@currentlabel` generated by `\caption` is lost after `\end{center}`

Comment: I think the main issue is the compiling twice!

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Maybe I am right. If there is no `\refstepcounter` before the \label (being outside of a group), the `\@currentlabel` is just empty, so `\ref` will typeset nothing actually, but not `??`

Comment: BTW: (La)TeX makes the cross-references not Texstudio. Texstudio is mainly an editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First of all [you should not use `center` environment but `\centering` to center a single figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables). Then you should note: `\label` should always be on the same group level as the element to be labeled and behind (or sometimes inside) that element. Here the `\label` should refer to the counter of the `\caption`. So `\label` should be placed usually behind the `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
  See figure~\ref{fig:a}.
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{a}
    \label{fig:a}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Nevertheless, after the first LaTeX run you will still get the `??`:

[image: ??]

This is, because `\label` only writes the label information to the `aux`-file and LaTeX reads it from the `aux`-file at the `\begin{document}` of the next LaTeX run. So `\ref` always shows information from the last LaTeX run instead of the current LaTeX run.

After the second LaTeX run you will see:

[image: with reference]

So if you add a new label you need always at least two LaTeX runs to see the label information in the references.