# Unexpected spacing in \newenvironment

Tags: spacing, environments

**Disclaimer:** I am asking this question because (1) I would like to solve this problem, but (2) *also* because I would like to learn about what's going on under the hood with LaTeX here. Thus, I am not seeking out a package that can do this, or comments on how or why I'm doing this. I simply want an explanation of the behavior *in this specific instance*.

I am playing with creating a new environment with the \newenvironment command. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{mytitle}{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    \LARGE\bfseries
}{
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytitle}
Lorem Ipsum Dipsum Gypsum
\end{mytitle}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Bad example]

**Question:** Where is that space coming from between the end of the text and the rule? I have tried putting percent signs all over the place, changing the `\parskip` value, doing different kinds of line breaks, etc. What is causing this? The natural followup question is how to get rid of it, so that it looks more like this:

[image: Good example]

Comment: The `{` followed by a new line enters a space. New lines are spaces. Use `%` to comment the line ending. It doesn't happen before because the line ending is preceded by a control sequence, which gobbles the space.

Comment: @cfr Unfortunately that has no effect

Comment: try inserting `\par` just after the brace that opens the "end of environment" block.  (not tested)  i think you're still in horizontal mode, and since the rule is the full textwidth, it will be set on a new line, at the baseline.  (don't have a tex installation on my laptop, so this is just a somewhat educated guess.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unfortunately that did not work either!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is correctly described by barbara in her comment but the solution needs more than just a `\par`: when the rule is drawn in your code it's at the baseline of the `\LARGE` paragraph. So you need to end that paragraph (which is what the `\par` does) and then go back to the normal baseline (which is what `\normalsize` does.)

When TeX sets a fontsize, it sets two sizes: the fontsize itself, and the leading (baseline height). So your `\LARGE` command sets the fontsize to 18pt and the leading to 22pt.  So the total height of a line is 22pt.  This height will remain in place until you change it or the group ends. So in your code, the rule is drawn on a line that is 22pt, which is where the extra vertical space comes from.

The command `\normalsize` in a 10pt document sets the fontsize to 10pt on a 12pt baseline. This can only be done after the `\par` is issued to end the previous paragraph.

You don't really need the inner `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` environment; this could be done by adding `\centering` instead of the `\begin{center}` and removing the inner `\end{center}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newenvironment{mytitle}{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    \LARGE\bfseries
}{  \par\normalsize
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytitle}
Lorem Ipsum Dipsum Gypsum
\end{mytitle}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This did it. Can you please help with part (2) of the question? What do `\par` and `normalsize` do here? Why are each needed?

Comment: @DavidM. I've elaborated a bit (more or less what barbara said.) Is that clearer now?

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to the normal baseline"? What did the rule do to the baseline?

Comment: the rule didn't do anything to the baseline -- the `\normalsize` caused the baseline to decrease.  another approach is to shift the rule upwards, which is what @carlatex's approach does.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is there a significant difference between this approach and CarLaTeX's approach?

Comment: there are many different ways to do some things with (la)tex.  often the choice between them comes down to which one you happen to think of first, or are more familiar with.  i learned tex before latex existed, so i tend to think of more "primitive" methods first.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ahhh sounds about right. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidM. More explanation. :)  There's not too much difference between my approach except for where @CarLaTeX got her `.4\baselineskip` value from (is is principled or eyeballed?)

Comment: Eyeballed, my answer is only a workaround, yours is the correct one!

Comment: @AlanMunn: This is maybe a silly question, but wouldn't the inserted `\par` sometimes cause a page break before the closing rule? If yes, how to avoid it? Would a simple `\nopagebreak` just before the closing rule work in all cases?

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is Alan Munn's one, however, as a workaround, you could raise a bit your rule adding `[.4\baselineskip]`, the `\rule` macro syntax is:

```
\rule[raise]{width}{thickness}
```

As for `\centering` instead of `center` environment, Barbara Beeton has already answered in her comment, however, see here: [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newenvironment{mytitle}
{%
\begin{center} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt} 
\LARGE\bfseries\centering 
}{%
\rule[.4\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{0.4pt} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{center}
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{mytitle} 
Lorem Ipsum Dipsum Gypsum
\end{mytitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my editor (modulo the `linewidt` thing), and unfortunately it had no effect...

Comment: @DavidM. Sorry, a cut and past error, try now (I'm working on my smartphone at the moment and it's a bit difficult)

Comment: I totally understand! Your newest edit works. Can you please explain what the [.4\baselineskip] does? Also, why did you change from the `center` environment to `\centering`?

Comment: (poking my nose in again.)  `center` adds space above and below.  `\centering' does not.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am sorry I cannot accept both answers!

Comment: @barbara I don't think the issue is  due to `{center}` vs `\centering`.

Comment: @DavidM. See my edit, don't worry, they correct answer is Alan's one, mine is only a workaround!

Comment: @AlanMunn -- i don't think so either, since the additional space would be symmetrical.  but the (implied) question was, what is the difference between the two.  there are many situations (usually in floating environments) where the additional space from `center` is distinctly unwanted because it causes the final object to be so large that it results in unwanted page breaks or "relocations".