# Table goes out of order due to label and caption

Tags: captions

```
\section{Required Resources}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{6cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
     \hline
     Sr.No. & Equipment  & Availaibility \\ [0.5ex]
     \hline\hline
     1 & Arduino UNO & Yes \\
     \hline
     2 & Flex Sensors  & Yes \\
     \hline
     3 & ZigBee Module  & No \\
     \hline
     4 & Servomotors  & Yes \\
     \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Required Resources}
 \label{tab:Required Resources}

\end{center}
\end{table}

\section{Milestones and Time Division}
\subsection{Seventh Semester}
\begin{table}[!]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
     \hline
     Sr.No. & Milestones  & Duration(Weeks) \\ [0.5ex]
     \hline\hline
     1 & Project Allocation and Confirmation & 01 \\
     \hline
     2 & Collecting relevant data for the project & 02 \\
     \hline
     3 & Understanding the project and literature review & 04 \\
     \hline
     4 & Project Definition Document & 02 \\
     \hline
     5 & Understanding the software which is used for the working of robotic arm & 04 \\
     \hline
     6 & Preparation of the presentation to be delivered at the end of the semester & 03 \\
     \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Milestones in Seventh Semester}
 \label{tab:Milestones in Seventh Semester}

\end{center}
\end{table}

\subsection{Eighth Semester}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
 \hline
 Sr.No. & Milestones  & Duration(Weeks) \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 &Learn to have full control on the robot  & 03 \\
 \hline
 2 & Understanding the software which is used to make the robotic arm as wireless & 03 \\
 \hline
 3 & Midsemester Exam & 01 \\
 \hline
 4 & Hardware implementation of module on the robotic arm to make it wireless & 03 \\
 \hline
 5 & Trials and validation & 01 \\
 \hline
 6 & Improvements if required & 01 \\
 \hline
 \hline
 7 & End semester presentation & 03 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Milestones in Eighth Semester}
 \label{tab:Milestones in Eighth Semester}
```

Comment: Please explain what your problem is instead of just showing us code. As for the code, complete the [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can compile and see the problem.

Comment: See [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not provide an MWE, I can only guess what might have gone wrong. You probably want to change the order of `\caption{...}` and `\end{center}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Required Resources}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{6cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
     \hline
     Sr.No. & Equipment  & Availaibility \\ [0.5ex]
     \hline\hline
     1 & Arduino UNO & Yes \\
     \hline
     2 & Flex Sensors  & Yes \\
     \hline
     3 & ZigBee Module  & No \\
     \hline
     4 & Servomotors  & Yes \\
     \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
 \caption{Required Resources}
 \label{tab:Required Resources}
\end{table}

\section{Milestones and Time Division}
\subsection{Seventh Semester}
\begin{table}[!]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
     \hline
     Sr.No. & Milestones  & Duration(Weeks) \\ [0.5ex]
     \hline\hline
     1 & Project Allocation and Confirmation & 01 \\
     \hline
     2 & Collecting relevant data for the project & 02 \\
     \hline
     3 & Understanding the project and literature review & 04 \\
     \hline
     4 & Project Definition Document & 02 \\
     \hline
     5 & Understanding the software which is used for the working of robotic arm & 04 \\
     \hline
     6 & Preparation of the presentation to be delivered at the end of the semester & 03 \\
     \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
 \caption{Milestones in Seventh Semester}
 \label{tab:Milestones in Seventh Semester}
\end{table}

\subsection{Eighth Semester}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{7cm}|p{3cm}|}
 \hline
 Sr.No. & Milestones  & Duration(Weeks) \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 &Learn to have full control on the robot  & 03 \\
 \hline
 2 & Understanding the software which is used to make the robotic arm as wireless & 03 \\
 \hline
 3 & Midsemester Exam & 01 \\
 \hline
 4 & Hardware implementation of module on the robotic arm to make it wireless & 03 \\
 \hline
 5 & Trials and validation & 01 \\
 \hline
 6 & Improvements if required & 01 \\
 \hline
 \hline
 7 & End semester presentation & 03 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Milestones in Eighth Semester}
 \label{tab:Milestones in Eighth Semester}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

And/or, as @Werner says, you may want to replace the `center` environments by a `\centering` before `\begin{tabular}`. This will reduce the space between the tables and the rest.