# Issue with Three Part Table and TexWorks

Tags: texworks, threeparttable

I'm transferring some latex code form sharelatex to texworks, and although this code works perfectly in sharelatex, it seems to be hiccuping on the three parttable in texworks. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[portrait 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parskip}{.25cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}
\title{Tablet Data Report}
\author{Cory}
\date{}

\def \OutputPath {"C:/Users/ifmr/Dropbox/Education v2/Clean Data Pipes, 2018/Analysis/launcher/Output/"}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Summary Statistics}

\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Cumulative Session Length (Hours)}
    \label{}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{300pt}{!}{
            \begin{threeparttable}
                \begin{tabular}{4*{6}c}
                    \input{\OutputPath Tables/cumulative_length}
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        }
    \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{\OutputPath Graphs/weekly_duration}
        \caption{Average Session Length By Week}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The actual code for the table is below:

```
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Class}} \\
\textbf{School}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{Total} \\
\midrule
Asharfabad&2.13&1.87&2.28&2.95&2.56&11.78 \\
RN3&0.24&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.63&0.86 \\
Seiko&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.75&0.75 \\
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your column definition`\begin{tabular}{4*{6}c}`. How many are your actual columns?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I just updated my question to include table for the code. I"m not very good at latex so I don't know if row headers count as a column, but I'm pretty sure there are six columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put a note without a `\item` use `para` option in the `tablenotes` environment.

Moreover:

1. Look at [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)
2. avoid using `resizebox` to resize a table, it is better to use the appropriate font, for example `\large` (but in this case the normalsize caption is awful, in my opinion, I wouldn't change the font at all).
3. since you loaded `dcolumn`, use it for better number alignment.

I have also loaded `array` to add some space between rows modifying `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass[portrait 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
 \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parskip}{.25cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}
\title{Tablet Data Report}
\author{Cory}
\date{}

\def \OutputPath {"C:/Users/ifmr/Dropbox/Education v2/Clean Data Pipes, 2018/Analysis/launcher/Output/"}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Summary Statistics}

    \begin{table}[H]\centering\large
        \caption{Cumulative Session Length (Hours)\label{alabel}}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{l*{5}{d{1.2}}d{2.2}}
                & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Class}} \\
                \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
                \textbf{School}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{1}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{2}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{3}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{4}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{5}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Total}} \\
                \midrule
                Asharfabad&2.13&1.87&2.28&2.95&2.56&11.78 \\
                RN3&0.24&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.63&0.86 \\
                Seiko&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.75&0.75 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            If your table doesn't have a note, why do you use threeparttable?
        \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Average Session Length By Week}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

Since you can't change your input file, the best alignment, in my opition is `r`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{cumulative_length.tex}
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Class}} \\
\textbf{School}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{Total} \\
\midrule
Asharfabad&2.13&1.87&2.28&2.95&2.56&11.78 \\
RN3&0.24&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.63&0.86 \\
Seiko&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.75&0.75 \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[portrait 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry} 
\usepackage{array} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\setlength{\parskip}{.25cm} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} 
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}} 
\title{Tablet Data Report} 
\author{Cory} 
\date{} 
\def \OutputPath {"C:/Users/ifmr/Dropbox/Education v2/Clean Data Pipes, 2018/Analysis/launcher/Output/"} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle \section{Summary Statistics} 
\begin{table}[H]\centering\large 
\caption{Cumulative Session Length (Hours)\label{alabel}} 
\begin{threeparttable} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{r}}
\toprule
 \input{cumulative_length}
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft] 
If your table doesn't have a note, why do you use threeparttable? 
\end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table} 
\begin{figure}[H]\centering 
\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{Average Session Length By Week}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm using the stata package tabout to output a table to latex form, so I'm sorta stuck with the actual table contents, but your advice on the code before and after has really helped!

Comment: @Cory Which is the part you can't change? What you posted as "the actual code for the table"?

Comment: Yes exactly. I use the tabout command with many different data so needed a way to work with its format. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Cory See my edit. The `filecontents*` environment at the beginning is only to create a `cumulative_length.tex` file, of course you don't need to use it because you already have the file :)