# How to center a figure with \centering

Tags: beamer, includegraphics, center

There is the same question  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449578/basic-how-can-i-stop-centering-a-text) for the text, it works fine, but it doesn't work for `\includgraphics`, how to use the same for the figure?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny   \lipsum[1-1]

\centering{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \tiny   \lipsum[1-1]
        
    \begingroup\centering\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}\endgroup
        
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is nothing special about `\includegraphics` you would center an image in exactly the same way as you would center an `X`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to end the paragraph before switching back to non-centred text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tiny   \lipsum[1-1]

\centering\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}

\lipsum[1-1]
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \tiny   \lipsum[1-1]
        
    \begingroup\centering\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}\par\endgroup
        
    \lipsum[1-1]
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]