# Making Tables and Placing Them in TeX

Tags: tables, enumerate, alignment

I made a table using some website

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
            \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mathematical \\ Term\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}English \\ Expression\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Symbolic \\ Term\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}Truth \\ \\ Table\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
            &                                                                           &                                                                      & \textbf{p}                                 & \textbf{p'}                                \\ \cline{4-5} 
            Negation                                                                 & Not P                                                                     & p'                                                                   & T                                          & F                                          \\ \cline{4-5} 
            &                                                                           &                                                                      & F                                          & T                                          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I placed it under my `\begin{enumerate}` I faced this issue

[image]

I don't know how to:

1) Make the table have some padding so that the borders don't look like its squishing the table

2) Move the table to under/center it relative to `1)`

Hoping someone can show me how to do these. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `float` environment.  Float environments are not designed to work as you appear to wish.  To do what you want, get rid of the float environment.

Here's something that *perhaps* achieves what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item The negation of $p$, denoted by $\neg p$, 
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
                \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Mathematical \\ Term\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}English \\ Expression\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Symbolic \\ Term\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{r|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}Truth \\ \\ Table\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
                &                                                                           &                                                                      & \textbf{p}                                 & \textbf{p'}                                \\ \cline{4-5} 
                Negation                                                                 & Not P                                                                     & p'                                                                   & T                                          & F                                          \\ \cline{4-5} 
                &                                                                           &                                                                      & F                                          & T                                          \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%%
    \end{center}
  \item something else
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, unless your lines fill the width of the page, this can look awkward or a bit off.  But, by removing the `table` (*float*) environment you'll have greater control to place the table where you want.

There are other approaches to centering objects on the page.  The question ["When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/22413) contains some information you might find useful.

Incidentally, I suspect you wrote `~p` expecting to get

[image]

But, that's not going to work.  `~` creates an unbreakable space.  It's generally used between words you don't want broken across lines such as with short titles and last names: `Mr.~So-and-so`.

To get the *squiggle*, you can do something like, `${\sim}p$`.  Generally, `\sim` is a binary relation, which has extra whitespace padding built in around it.  The brackets essentially *remove* this padding.

Also, personally, I find `$p^\prime$` (or `$p'$`) looks much better than `p'` outside of a math context.

Comment: I used `p'` here due to the fact that I needed it to be bolded. Thanks for the assistance! I am still learning TeX and this was quite helpful!

Comment: Getting math content to be bolded can be quite frustrating at times.  But for `p'`, you can get this bold using `$\mathbf{p'}$`.