# Strange behaviour using center, tcolorbox, listings and enumerate

Tags: errors, listings, enumerate, tcolorbox, compilation-error

I have a problem compiling the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{lstlisting}
            alert(123);
        \end{lstlisting}

        boom

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I cannot reduce anything and don't know if the problem is dedicated to listings, tcolorbox, enumerate or center. (maybe all of them together)

The error is

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 ^^I^^I^^I\item o
                     ne
```

which is (like most LaTeX errors) not very useful…

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  If you remove `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` and instead use `{\centering.... }%` the problem is resolved.  Plus using the `center` environment is adding additional vertical space -- which is usually not desired.  See [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/4301).

Comment: What's the `center` environment supposed to do? The `lstlisting` environment will use the whole text width anyway.

Comment: Why using the `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` environment or the `\centering` command while we could simply use the `tcolorbox` environment with the `center` option?

 `\begin{tcolorbox}[center] ... \end{tcolorbox}`

Answer (score 2):

The `\begin{center}` confuses `tcolorbox` besides adding undesirable additional vertical space. Either add `\leavevmode` before `\begin{tcolorbox}` or better use `{\centering.... }` as suggested by @PeterGrill in a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\leavevmode
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        alert(123);
    \end{lstlisting}
    boom
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to include a `\par`: `{\centering ... \par}`.

Answer (score 1):

### Update: removal of borders.

It seems to me that from your own response to your problem that you don't want the listing to be in a visible box. And as with tcolorbox, everything is configurable, just set it up.

- With the `skin=empty` parameter, nothing is drawn at all: so there is no border (see page 237).
- With the parameter `lowerbox=ignored` not to display the lower part of the box (see p 24).

It is therefore also possible to set the distances between the content of the listing and the rest of the box, but i did not do.

[image: second box]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcblisting}{skin=empty,lowerbox=ignored}
            alert(123);
        \end{tcblisting}

        boom

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### Old answer:

It is possible to use the `dispListing` environment of the tcolorbox `documentation` library (see page 465 of the 4.14 manual).

[image: displisting]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \begin{dispListing}
            alert(123);
        \end{dispListing}

        boom

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @AboAmmar , @PeterGrill and @egreg who managed to find out the source of the error namely the *center* environment.

To get the the `tcolorbox` centered we can use its `center` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill % this rule is added to show that the box is actually centered

    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.75\linewidth,center]
        \begin{lstlisting}
            alert(123);
        \end{lstlisting}

        boom

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \noindent\hrulefill 


\end{document}
```

[image]