# Area under curve in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={},axis x line=center, axis y 
line=center, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, xlabel style={right}, ylabel style= 
{above},ticks=none]
\addplot[color=brown,domain=-0.1:1.1,samples=100]{(2*x-1)^4};
\addplot[domain=7/8:1.1,samples=100]{8*x-7};
\end{axis}
\node [] at (3.4,0.2) {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph of $y = (2x-1)^4$ (brown) and the tangent function (black) at 
the point $(1,1)$.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Hi there I'm not too sure how to shade the region between the tangent function and the curve.
Some help would be awesome!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Off-topic: don't use `center` environment within `figure`, use `\centering`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! One way is to use `fillbetween`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={},axis x line=center, axis y 
line=center, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, xlabel style={right}, ylabel style= 
{above},ticks=none]
\addplot[color=brown,domain=-0.1:1.1,samples=100,name path=curve]{(2*x-1)^4};
\addplot[domain=7/8:1.1,samples=101,name path=tangent]{8*x-7+0.01};
\draw[name path=axis] (0,0) -- (7/8,0);
\node [anchor=south] at (0.5,0) {$P$};
\end{axis}
\path [name path=aux1,%draw=blue,%->,fill=orange,
intersection segments={of=curve and axis,
    sequence={R3[reverse]--L3}}];
\begin{scope}[on background layer]      
 \path [fill=orange,
 intersection segments={of=aux1 and tangent,
     sequence={L1--R1}}];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But in this case you can certainly do the fills without `fillbetween`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabels={},yticklabels={},axis x line=center, axis y 
line=center, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, xlabel style={right}, ylabel style= 
{above},ticks=none]
\addplot[color=brown,domain=-0.1:1.1,samples=101]{(2*x-1)^4};
\addplot[domain=7/8:1.1,samples=2]{8*x-7};
\node [anchor=south] at (0.5,0) {$P$};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]      
 \fill[orange] plot[variable=\x,domain=0.5:1.1,samples=51] (\x,{(2*\x-1)^4})
 -- (1.1,{8*1.1-7})-- (7/8,0);
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]