# Environment definition adds vertical space above

Tags: spacing, environments

I already have found the solution to define a new environment without the additional space above the paragraph. But why does the "vanilla" way of defining this not work?

## Pictures

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
DIV=12,
paper=a4,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% the GOOD definition
\newenvironment{goodgood}{\ignorespaces\par\centering\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}\small\sffamily}{\end{minipage}\par\ignorespacesafterend}

%%% the PROBLEMATIC definition
\newenvironment{asdf}{\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}\small\sffamily}{\end{minipage}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

ABC
\begin{asdf}
    bad vertical spacing
\end{asdf}

DEF
\begin{goodgood}
    GOOD VERTICAL SPACING
\end{goodgood}

AAA
\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK `\begin{center}...\end{center}` adds space. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/35864. So if you don't want additional space (which together with a `minipage` could add up), `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is probably not your weapon of choice.

Comment: As for the error: In the MWE `\singlespacing` is undefined. LaTeX throws an error (which should not be ignored!), but continues pretending `\singlespacing` wasn't there.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need the `\ignorespaces` at the beginning of the environment definition. It seems somewhat pointless to suppress spaces there, since they would have to come from the macro definition itself and there aren't any. I'm also not sure if the `\ignorespacesafterend` is needed here.

Comment: Right, totally forgot `setspace`. Thanks! Also, I played around with `\ignorespaces` and you are right with that as well!

Comment: @moewe Thank you, you can make your edit into an answer and I would mark it as solved.

Comment: It's a bit later for me now, but I will write up an answer tomorrow if no one complains about what I commented here.

Comment: also `\ignorespaces\par` is the same as `\par` as there are no spaces between `\ignorespaces` and `\par`.

Comment: I made a mistake. What I was aiming for was the "problematic" example, but at some points in my document, it adds to much space above the env. With the "good" definition in the code above, it lacks some space below the env. But now that I put the ignore spaces-commands into the "problematic" definition above, it all works as intended as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/35864) `\begin{center}...\end{center}` is implemented via a list (`\trivlist`) and causes vertical space before and after the centred text. `\centering` on the other hand will not add additional vertical space.

That means that your `asdf` environment gets the 'usual' vertical spacing of a display environment, while `goodgood` just gets the spacing one gets when moving on to the next paragraph (due to the `\par`).

You don't need the `\ignorespaces` at the beginning of `goodgood`: `\ignorespaces\par` is the same as `\par` as David Carlisle pointed out in the comments. Since the environment ends with a `\par` I also don't think the `\ignorespacesafterend` is required.

Comment: To add some evenly divided space above and below, is it good practice to simply add `\vspace{2.0ex}` at the beginning and end? Like this: -> `\newenvironment{specialnote}{\vspace{2ex}\par\centering\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}\small\sffamily}{\end{minipage}\par\vspace{2ex}}` (You switched `asdf` and `goodgood`, btw.)

Comment: @henry Thanks for catching the name confusion (I hope the edit fixed it). I'm not sure about best practices with `\vspace`. I'd have thought it would be more natural to use `\trivlist` or a `\list`, but I'm not sure what one would have to do to get what you wanted then. Maybe you should ask a new question about that.