# In the figure form, how to adjust the whole size of "text" and "math" format at once?

Tags: math-mode, floats, text, size, gather

> In the figure form, how to adjust the whole size of "text" and "math" format "as a combined figure" at once?

If this is a usual pdf figure, we can do \includegraphics[width=4.4in], such as below, the size is tuned by `[width=4.4in]`

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4.4in]{.pdf}
  \caption{}\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Can we adjust the whole overall size of the figure (including the "text" and "math" format) at once by the similar function, like "size"?

> I hope to have a 3-times-larger figure overall.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{gather*}
\overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times
           \underbrace{C\times {D}}_{EFG}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\underbrace{\kern5em}_{\text{family}}
\end{gather*}
\end{center}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  \mathindent=0pt
  \begin{gather*}
    \overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times
               \underbrace{C\times {D}}_{EFG}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    \underbrace{\hphantom{A\times B\times C\times D}}_{\text{family}}
    \end{gather*}
  \end{varwidth}}
  \caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\resizebox` you can also use `\scalebox`:

```
[...]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\scalebox{3}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, may I make sure the complete code for your "\scalebox"?

Comment: yes. By the way: If you do not need the environment `gather*` then it can be done in an easier way: `\scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle\overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times ...$}`

Comment: actually you taught me to use "gather*" - -what was that purpose in a previous post you answer? Thanks!!!

Comment: It depends on what you want: Only one time an equation as big as possible or an equation as part of a document with other equations? In the first case it doesn't matter what you use ...

Comment: Thanks -- but what is the preamble needed for \scalebox{...}? 

This looks not compilable simply from "\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}"

Comment: Package `graphicx` is needed, but it is loaded already by `mathtools`. At least in my TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks +1, I accept your answer,  but -- my real question is the following: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467729/41144  --- I dont find it fully resolved.

Comment: May I also know what is the use of "  \mathindent=0pt" this causes some problem in my compilation in  tex.stackexchange.com/q/467729/41144

Comment: Amsmath is a bit tricky if you want to resize a formula. With `fleqn` it puts the equation left aligned but with an indentation of `mathindent` from the left margin. This is the reason why it must be set to 0 pt

Answer (score 3):

If you want to resize content using a specific width/height, then you can use `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}` (using `!` to maintain the aspect ratio if you only specify one or the other). If you want to scale content using a number, you can use `\scalebox{<num>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \scalebox{3}{$\displaystyle % If needed...
    \underbrace{
      \overbrace{
        \underbrace{
          A \times B
        }_E \times \underbrace{
          C \times D
        }_{EFG}
      }^{\text{ABCDEFG}}
    }_{\text{family}}
  $}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've nested the `family` `\underbrace` as part of the bigger expression, so there's no need to manually place it based on the location. Also note [the use of `\centering` rather than the `center` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764), and there's no need for using `gather`.

Comment: +1 Thanks,  I like your answer, -- my real question is the following: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467729/41144  I dont find it fully resolved.