# Problem with Caption under wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

I am encountering this problem with the caption (see the accompanying picture). I have tried all ways, but it just wouldn't work. Can somebody help me figure out what's wrong and how to fix it?

The error message is as follows:

"Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation of the `wrapfig' package(caption) package *right after* the`float' package. \begin{wrapfigure}"
[image]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your post and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces your error. And don't use `center` environment but `\centering` within a `wrapfigure` environment, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering.

Comment: Are your `caption` and `float` packages up-to-date?  This message is loaded via `\caption@If@Package@Loaded` command in `caption`.  It seems that it likely needs a newer version of `float` than what it found.