# How to center image in beamer when also using \only?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
% \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\only<1>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill}%
\only<2>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill}%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How do I center the images when in `\only`? The second `\hfill` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried `\hfill`s outside the `\only`, but that didn't work as well.

[image: hfill not working with only]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex gave you already some options for how to center the images. Assuming that you wish to stick to your syntax (in order to avoid the extra vertical space introduced by `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, you could just insert a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
% \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\only<1>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill\strut}%
\only<2>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill\strut}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I would actually top-align the content.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
% \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\only<1>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill\strut}%
\only<2>{\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill\strut}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` in place of the `\hfill`s inside the `\only`s, like so:

```
\only<1>{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}\end{center}}%
\only<2>{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}\end{center}}%
```

(Alternatively, you can wrap both `\only`s in one set of `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`s.

```
\begin{center}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\end{center}
```

Note that `\centering` is not recommended in this context ([When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650)) and would center subsequent text.

If you decide to use the figure environment (`\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`) to encapsulate the `\includegraphics`', you'd use `\centering` inside that.