# Scale down the size of a PGF figure

Tags: matplotlib

I've created a plot using `matplotlib` in Python and saved it to a PGF which I've then embedded in my LaTeX document. I'd like it to be a bit smaller, as is it won't centre and it forces down a section's header which is supposed to be above it.

Here's the link for the pgf file
http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=191033

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{COMP 2823: Assignment 1}
\author{Student ID: 480380498}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{SID: 480380498}

\begin{document}
...

\newpage
\section{}
Text \\
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\input{graph1.pgf}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not using \includegraphics presently, I'm using \input but I'll try this anyway.
edit: just tested it, include graphics doesn't work with pgf files
I'll amend my OP to include the LaTeX code

Comment: your code is not compileable

Comment: I only posted a fragment of it, as is the entire thing compiles.
I'll include the preamble as well for context.

Comment: Can you add the code from the image `graph1.pgf`, otherwise we can't compile your example?

Comment: It's much too long, it was made by matplotlib. Could I upload the file somehow?

Comment: You can provide a link to an online code storage site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{COMP 2823: Assignment 1}
\author{Student ID: 480380498}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{SID: 480380498}

\begin{document}
    ...

    \newpage% why a newpage?
    \section{without title?}
    Text % don't use \\, leave a blank line to create a new paragraph   

    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{graph1.pgf}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

(Not tested because I don't have a .pgf file).

And see also: [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering)

Comment: This does the job of resizing the img, but it still displaces the section header.
Also I just wanted to put the next section of the document on a new page, no real reason.
P.s. I tried to vote for your answer but my rep's too low :(

Comment: @MarvinGaTeX If you don't want the figure floating (that is, going around where LaTeX puts it), just use `center` instead of `figure`. See my renewed code.