# Caption of tikzpicture and modify vertical space

Tags: captions, tikz-pic

Caption of tikzpicture placed in wrong postion (see image)

My code is:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{float}                                      
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
Example caption of Tikzpicture:
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0,xshift=6.0cm,yshift=0cm]
[circle,draw, very thick, color=red, minimum size=5.0cm, fill overzoom image=example-image-a]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof*{figure}{ABC}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can i put caption under tikzpicture and can change vertical space between caption/tikzpicture?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. See [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering/23653)
2. the option `overlay` is used to write "something" over "something else" and do not consider the dimension of "something", it's like "something" has no dimension, you don't have to use it for an ordinary picture
3. `fill overzoom image` is an option of `tcolorbox`, you need to load it
4. if you are in a `figure` environment, you do not need `\captionof`, use `\caption` instead.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
Example caption of Tikzpicture:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, very thick, color=red, minimum size=5.0cm, fill overzoom image=example-image-a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ABC}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* it's not very clear to me what you want to achieve, but if you want to horizontally move the picture *and* its caption, use a `minipage`, like here:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
In Fig.~\ref{fig:left} the image and its caption are on the left.
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, very thick, color=red, minimum size=5.0cm, fill overzoom image=example-image-a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ABC\label{fig:left}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

With \verb|\hspace{...}| you can shift them to the right as you like, see Fig.~\ref{fig:hspa}. 
\begin{figure}[htb]\hspace{5cm}
\begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, very thick, color=red, minimum size=5.0cm, fill overzoom image=example-image-a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ABC\label{fig:hspa}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

With \verb|\hfill| you can shift them completely to the right, see Fig.~\ref{fig:hfi}. 
\begin{figure}[htp]\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.42\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, very thick, color=red, minimum size=5.0cm, fill overzoom image=example-image-a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ABC\label{fig:hfi}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank so much. In my code: "anchor=north west,inner sep=0,xshift=6.0cm,yshift=0cm" - How can i put this image & caption in position (x cm, y cm)? Thanks

Comment: @latexforti with respect to the page?

Comment: this tikzimage placed center of page. Can you move this image with xshift, yshift? Thanks

Comment: see more in link. https://imgur.com/Cm5y8x4 . thanks

Comment: @latexforti See my edit and let me know if it's what you would like, thank you!