# Long abstract for technical report orphaning Abstract title due to vfil

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, titles, abstract

When using a custom template to prepare a report I noticed that long abstracts split across pages, fine, but it leaves the abstract title hanging by itself on it's own page.

How can I structure the abstract environment to have vertically centered abstracts if they fit on one page and top aligned in long abstracts? The `\vfil` is useful for centering short abstracts, but then means it orphans the title in long abstracts

### Actual Behavior of long abstracts

[image: Two page view of abstract title orphaned when the abstract content is long]

### The intended behaviour of long abstracts

[image]

### But without breaking short abstracts

[image]

### The MWE of abstract environment and usage

Normally the environment def is split into the template class.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil %Toggling this line will align to the top in multipage abstract
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\textsc\normalsize University \par}
    \bigskip
    {\underline{Abstract} \par}
    \bigskip
    {\textsc\normalsize Faculty \par}
    {\textsc\normalsize Department \par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize \underline{A progress report submitted for continuation towards a PhD}\par}
    \bigskip
    {\normalsize\bf \title \par}
    \medskip
    {\normalsize by [Author] \par}
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}

\title{\bf An MWE}
\author{for SO}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a simple approach without making many changes to your source code. By replacing the center environment `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` with the switch command `\centering` inside `\begingroup ... \endgroup` or between braces with `\par` gives the desired output.

```
\begingroup 
  \centering
   ...
\endgroup
```

or analogously

```
{\centering
  ...
  \par
}
```

### The intended behaviour of long abstracts

[image]

### But without breaking short abstracts

[image]

MWE (with `\begingroup ... \endgroup`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{abstract}
{
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfil\vfil
    \begingroup
        \centering
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        {\textsc\normalsize University \par}
        \bigskip
        {\underline{Abstract} \par}
        \bigskip
        {\textsc\normalsize Faculty \par}
        {\textsc\normalsize Department \par}
        \bigskip
        {\normalsize \underline{A progress report submitted for continuation towards a PhD}\par}
        \bigskip
        {\normalsize\bf \title \par}
        \medskip
        {\normalsize by [Author] \par}
        \bigskip
    \endgroup
}
{ 
    \vfil\vfil\null
    \cleardoublepage
}

\title{\bf An MWE}
\author{for SO}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\lipsum[1-6]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Was the original problem because of how LaTeX treats the ends of environments?

Comment: @EdL Honestly, I am not sure the reason why. Commenting the 1st `\null` (the same as `\hbox{}`) the issue with the long abstracts is solved, but the short ones are not vertically "centered". Just replacing the `center` environment with `\centering` it works, but the whole text is than centered. In the latter case, loading the `ragged2e` package lets you with `\justify` to typeset fully-justified back. The drawback is the same output as with the `center` environment. `center` is defined in terms of `trivlist` and leaves vertical space before and after it. This is not the case for `\centering`.

Comment: I see, thanks for letting me know about how that center environment is defined. Perhaps it is to do with the spacing below it that makes the LaTeX engine split the page there.
I think [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116601/98351) clearly shows how  the centre environment was the wrong implementation for my use case and centering is much better.