# Why is there whitespace below a center environment, but not when using \centering?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am trying to typeset some content to the top of the page and some to the bottom of the page and both should be centered. Initially I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    Top
    \vfill
    Bottom
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However this leaves whitespace between the word Bottom and the actual bottom of the page:

[image]

If I am using `\centering` instead I acheive my result, but I don't understand why and I thin the environment would be the more logic approach, then the `\centering` switch.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
{\centering
    Top
    \vfill
    Bottom

}
\end{document}
```

Result as expected:

[image]

The same is true for `flushleft` and I therefore think it might be expected behaviour, but would like to understand how to prevent it and use the correct approach.

Comment: because adding that white space is the main purpose of `center` as it is a "display" environemnt intended to offset an item from the surrounding text. There is an answer already on site, I'll find...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering/116601#116601

Comment: OK, so I defined my own environments which just call `\centering` and `\raggedright` and `\par` at the end. Do you want to mark this as a duplicate, or shall I answer what I did based on your comment?

Comment: question is a bit different but answer is same, I'll mark it as dup I think.