# Custom command for statement to be proved

Tags: command-line

I have created a code for a proof goal:

```tex
\centering{zz:\,$\{P,\,P \lif Q,\,Q \lif  R\}\,\sststile{AL}{}\,R$`
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to define a custom command which gives a very general recipe for this kind of code. It should have the following form:

```tex
\zz{formulas before the turnstile |- formula after the turnstile}[first argument of sststile, optional]
```

So in my example, it should be:

```tex
\zz{P,P \lif Q, Q \lif R|- R}[AL]
```

The command should work with any number for formulas before the turnstile, seperate them with a comma and add the extra space between them. Also, if I write `|=` instead of `|-` it should produce the double turnstile `\sdtstile`. How could I do that? I'm looking forward to your answers!

Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman, abstracton, leqno]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext} % removes italics from mathfont

\newcommand{\lif}{\rightarrow}

\begin{document}
\centering{zz:\,$\{P,\,P \lif Q,\,Q \lif  R\}\,\sststile{AL}{}\,R$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be *much* easier if you have two commands, `\zz{before}{after}[what]` for one type of turnstyle and `\ZZ{before}{after}[what]` for the other type. I imagine you can invent something with your syntax too, but it will need much more "TeXhacking" skills...

Comment: BTW, `\centering` gets no arguments, it's a switch: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering/23653

Answer (score 1):

First off, `\centering` does not work as you seem to think. I used `\[...\]` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{turnstile}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text

\newcommand{\lif}{\rightarrow}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\zz}{mO{}}
 {
  \vitus_zz_start:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vitus_zz_start:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \| \- } { #1 }
   {
    \vitus_zz_do:nnnn { |- } { \sststile } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \vitus_zz_do:nnnn { |= } { \sdtstile } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vitus_zz_do:nnnn
 {
  \[
  \mathrm{zz{:}\;}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 } { #3 }
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 }
  #2{#4}{}
  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 }
  \]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\zz{P,P \lif Q, Q \lif R |- R}[AL]
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\zz{P,P \lif Q, Q \lif R |- R}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\zz{P,P \lif Q, Q \lif R |= R}[AL]
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\zz{P,P \lif Q, Q \lif R |= R}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

The arguments are absorbed and the first (mandatory) one is analyzed to see whether it contains `|-`. If it does, `\sststile` is used, otherwise `\sdtstile`. Next the argument is split at either `|-` or `|=` according to the previous analysis and the line is formed.

[image]

Comment: @Rmano Yes, I'll fix! Thanks for noting.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so so much!