# Center environment doesn't center a TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, center

It seems to be lots of problems like this in the archive but none seems to match mine.

I have a TikZ figure that depends on `\draw`. I know that keys off an assumed Cartesian plane and maybe that is the problem with centering -- if so I might be screwed.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\SetA{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetB{(1,2) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetC{(2,0) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-3,-2) rectangle (5,4);
        \draw (4.5,3.5) node {$\mathcal{U}$};
        \draw (-2,2) node {$A \cap B$};
        \draw (4,2) node {$A \cap C$};
    \draw \SetA node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \SetB node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \SetC node [below] {$C$};

    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;  
      \fill[red] \SetB;  
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;
      \clip \SetB;
      \fill[green] \SetC;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Examples of Intersection}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Since I haven't figured out how to add a graphic I'll describe it: the TikZ figure is a little to the left and the caption appears to be centered. Of course. I'd like them both to be centered. (Maybe some kind person could explain what I should do After I click image to add same.)

Comment: For adding the image, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-be-included-in-a-question-or-answer?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `figure` environment within a `center` evironment, just use `figure` with `\centering`.

See [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering/23653).

I also added `caption` package for a better caption alignment.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\SetA{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetB{(1,2) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetC{(2,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-3,-2) rectangle (5,4);
        \draw (4.5,3.5) node {$\mathcal{U}$};
        \draw (-2,2) node {$A \cap B$};
        \draw (4,2) node {$A \cap C$};
    \draw \SetA node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \SetB node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \SetC node [below] {$C$};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;  
      \fill[red] \SetB;  
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;
      \clip \SetB;
      \fill[green] \SetC;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Examples of Intersection}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `center` without `figure`, in this case add the caption with `\captionof`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\SetA{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetB{(1,2) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\SetC{(2,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-3,-2) rectangle (5,4);
        \draw (4.5,3.5) node {$\mathcal{U}$};
        \draw (-2,2) node {$A \cap B$};
        \draw (4,2) node {$A \cap C$};
    \draw \SetA node[below] {$A$};
    \draw \SetB node [above] {$B$};
    \draw \SetC node [below] {$C$};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;  
      \fill[red] \SetB;  
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \SetA;
      \clip \SetB;
      \fill[green] \SetC;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Examples of Intersection}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The difference between the two is that `figure` floats (that is, LaTeX put it where it's better), whereas `center` does not (it is placed where it is).

Comment: Two answers for the price of one. Awesome! Thank you CarlaTeX. So much I don't know. And just in case anyone thinks I created this TikZ figure -- nope. Piecing things together from code stolen from here.

Comment: @TonyK As an old Italian COBOL programmer I told you only Spoletini wrote, all the others copy-pasted (Spoletini wrote a COBOL manual in Italian) :D Thank you for accepting my answer.